# How do I write json results to a div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

This is probably a really easy question, but I can't find anything that works.

I'm trying to take a json result and just write it into the inner html of a div to see what it looks like.

I have something like this:

```
$.getJSON("someurlthatgivesmejson",
    function(data){         
        $("#jsonmodel").html(data);  // what should this be??
    });
  });
```

**UPDATE**

I was able to get it to display some text by using

```
$("#jsonmodel").html($.param(data));
```

However, it's not formatted like how the browser displays a json result, like the structure of the javascript object.

Comment: How about just use Firebug/Fiddler to inspect your data?

Comment: @crescentfresh I'm doing that as a point of reference, but I wanted to get that type of output inside a div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [jquery-json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) library

```
`$('#jsonmodel').html($.toJSON(data));`
```

Comment: Is the library hosted by google by any chance?  I'm trying to get this working on their API Playground

Comment: No, I don't think so. may be you re-use code directly from http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/source/browse/trunk/jquery.json.js

Answer (score 2):

depends on what the data is. if you want to write it as a string, then you should use the $.get method to get it, that way its not converted into a js hash for you

Comment: Thanks, so I should do something like $("#jsonmodel").html($.get(data));?

Comment: That's not working for me.  I'm trying serialize as well but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Joseph: No, mkoryak meant `$.get("someurlthatgivesmejson")`

Comment: @crescentfresh I thought he might have meant that as well and I tried that too.  Still no dice.  I'm starting to think what I'm trying to do is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) natively within browsers and just pass in spacer arguments like this:

```js
JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
```

#### Demo in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/w4ufv8qb/) & Stack Snippets

```js
// listener
$(":input").on("keyup change", WriteFormDataToDiv);

// call on load
WriteFormDataToDiv()

function WriteFormDataToDiv() {
  var data = $(":input").serializeArray()
  var html = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
  $("#formdata").html(html)
}
```

```css
pre {
  padding: 15px;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="cat"     value="frida" />
<input type="text" name="dog"     value="buddy" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="food"    value="pizza" />
<input type="text" name="dessert" value="ice cream" />

<pre id="formdata"></pre>
```

#### Further Reading

- [How can I pretty-print JSON using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4810841/1366033)
- [How can I beautify JSON programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2614862/1366033)
- [Javascript: How to generate formatted easy-to-read JSON straight from an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3515523/1366033)

Answer (score 0):

data is a JavaScript object, you need a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I used:

```
function unjsEncode(string){
            var newstring = string.replace(/\\x/g,'%');
            newstring = newstring.replace(/\\n/g,'');
            newstring = newstring.replace(/\\"/g,'"');
            newstring = decodeURIComponent(newstring);
            return newstring;
    }
```

thanks to http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/169509-how-decrypt-garbled-javascript
And I hope this helps out!