# How can I beautify JSON programmatically?

Tags: javascript, json, code-formatting, pretty-print

Do you know of any "JSON Beautifier" for JavaScript?

**From**

```json
{"name":"Steve","surname":"Jobs","company":"Apple"}
```

**To**

```json
{
  "name" : "Steve",
  "surname" : "Jobs",
  "company" : "Apple"
}
```

**Example**

```js
some_magic(jsonObj); // return beautified JSON
```

Comment: Why do you need to beautify it programmatically? Is it being displayed on a web page?

Comment: I'm rather amused to see so many "solutions" referenced in the answers, all solving a problem that is, per Andy E's answer, already catered for by the standard API. A lesson to us all: read the documentation of existing APIs before either seeking or implementing a solution to a requirement ;-)

Answer (score 968, accepted):

#### Programmatic formatting solution:

The `JSON.stringify` method supported by many modern browsers (including IE8) can output a beautified JSON string:

```
JSON.stringify(jsObj, null, "\t"); // stringify with tabs inserted at each level
JSON.stringify(jsObj, null, 4);    // stringify with 4 spaces at each level
```

```
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/HZPVL/
```

This method is also included with [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), for supporting older browsers.

#### Manual formatting solution

If you don't need to do it programmatically, Try [JSON Lint](http://www.jsonlint.com/).  Not only will it prettify your JSON, it will validate it at the same time.

Comment: Awesome...thanks!  (It might be worth adding that `white-space:pre` in the css is needed as well)

Comment: on html page, wrap your output in <pre></pre> tags

Comment: I use JSON.stringify and [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) to output for debugging. [Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/absynce/ACGRx/)

Comment: Knew about `null, 2`, but didn't know that '\t' would work too. Fantastic!

Comment: I find jsonlint.com a little cumbersome. A MUCH quicker workflow is https://kadebom.com/jsonlint.html IMO

Comment: @luckybroman5 cumbersome? Literally copy, paste, click...

Comment: `JSON.stringify` does fairly horrible job on lists with lots of numbers, the npm package beautify-json (https://npm.io/package/beautify-json) does that better.

Comment: question was about json string as an input NOT object, so proper would be ` JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonString),null,2);  `