# How can I beautify JSON programmatically?

Tags: php, json

You might say this is duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614862/how-can-i-beautify-json-programmatically), but original question WASN'T answered there. Important part of question is: `programmatically`?

Is there any php function? Native or homemade?

Comment: I wonder if you could tweak this to make it work for JSON: http://beautifyphp.sourceforge.net/docs/

Comment: `json_decode` followed by output buffering of `var_dump` could work, although not the cleanest solution.

Comment: `nl2br(json_encode(json_decode('{"test":[{"my":"json"},{"string":"with"},{"pretty":"print"}]}'), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT))` Not talking about the performance though, do a perf test for your JSON on your own

Answer (score 167):

[json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) has a flag `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`

```
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

To improve the readability of the output, you can add flags like `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` and `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`

```
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: For a better styling, you could put your encoded JSON output between *<pre>* tags. Something like _<pre> YOUR_JSONDATA </pre>_

Answer (score 3):

had the same question right now. But as you also i'm having php < 5.4. Zend Framework has Zend_Json::prettyPrint(). Works very well.

Answer (score 3):

I created a non-destructive JSON beautifier that support multiple deep levels.

```
/**
 * JSON beautifier
 * 
 * @param string    The original JSON string
 * @param   string  Return string
 * @param string    Tab string
 * @return string
 */
function pretty_json($json, $ret= "\n", $ind="\t") {

    $beauty_json = '';
    $quote_state = FALSE;
    $level = 0; 

    $json_length = strlen($json);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $json_length; $i++)
    {                               

        $pre = '';
        $suf = '';

        switch ($json[$i])
        {
            case '"':                               
                $quote_state = !$quote_state;                                                           
                break;

            case '[':                                                           
                $level++;               
                break;

            case ']':
                $level--;                   
                $pre = $ret;
                $pre .= str_repeat($ind, $level);       
                break;

            case '{':

                if ($i - 1 >= 0 && $json[$i - 1] != ',')
                {
                    $pre = $ret;
                    $pre .= str_repeat($ind, $level);                       
                }   

                $level++;   
                $suf = $ret;                                                                                                                        
                $suf .= str_repeat($ind, $level);                                                                                                   
                break;

            case ':':
                $suf = ' ';
                break;

            case ',':

                if (!$quote_state)
                {  
                    $suf = $ret;                                                                                                
                    $suf .= str_repeat($ind, $level);
                }
                break;

            case '}':
                $level--;   

            case ']':
                $pre = $ret;
                $pre .= str_repeat($ind, $level);
                break;

        }

        $beauty_json .= $pre.$json[$i].$suf;

    }

    return $beauty_json;

}
```

Comment: case ':' needs to evaluate `quote_state`, otherwise timestamps will get corrupted....

Answer (score 2):

This simple trick did the job for me, I didn't wanted any additional libraries or functions:

```
$json = '{"status":"0","status_translated":"Request successful!","data":"1"}';
$json_beautified = str_replace(array("{", "}", '","'), array("{<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", "<br />}", '",<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"'), $json);
```

And the result looks like this:

```
{
    "status":"0",
    "status_translated":"Request successful!",
    "data":"1"
}
```

This is only for json code that goes 1 step in depth, I hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

For command line usage, you can use the js beautifier. No need to share your data with external sites.

https://github.com/vivekpathak/tools/blob/master/jb/jb