# ExtJs textarea with formatting

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, textarea

I'm trying to add formatted json string to my textarea field. But it doesn't work.

I'm formatting string using this approach: [How can I beautify JSON programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614862/how-can-i-beautify-json-programmatically)

and then just call

```
textarea.setValue(formattedJson);
```

Check the snapshot of result:

[image]

Is it poosible to get correctly formatted string in the textarea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `JSON.stringify` method takes **Object** as parameter. You probably send **string** as parameter. This is correct code:

```
jsonObj = {a: 'b', c: [1,2,3]};
// note that jsonObj is object, not string
jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, '\t');

textarea.setValue(jsonString);
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/JNqaX/)