# Prettify JSON Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSON pretty print using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/json-pretty-print-using-javascript)

I'm working on a project that will be used to help analyse and understand JSON arrays by future developers of a platform. I'm referencing Facebook's brilliant Graph Explorer page, [seen here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), and want to output our array in a prettified, correctly tab indented and line breaker array, just as it does on the explorer.

The arrays are outputted to a `textarea`, and because of this I think I'm running into issues with the line breaking and tabbing. I've also tried using the prettify library, but with no luck.

Example:

```
{"outcome" : "success", "result" : {"name" : "messaging-sockets", "default-interface" : "external", "include" : [], "socket-binding" : {"messaging" : {"name" : "messaging", "interface" : null, "port" : 5445, "fixed-port" : null, "multicast-address" : null, "multicast-port" : null}, "messaging-throughput" : {"name" : "messaging-throughput", "interface" : null, "port" : 5455, "fixed-port" : null, "multicast-address" : null, "multicast-port" : null}}}, "compensating-operation" : null}
```

To:

```
{
   "outcome":"success",
   "result":{
      "name":"messaging-sockets",
      "default-interface":"external",
      "include":[

      ],
      "socket-binding":{
         "messaging":{
            "name":"messaging",
            "interface":null,
            "port":5445,
            "fixed-port":null,
            "multicast-address":null,
            "multicast-port":null
         },
         "messaging-throughput":{
            "name":"messaging-throughput",
            "interface":null,
            "port":5455,
            "fixed-port":null,
            "multicast-address":null,
            "multicast-port":null
         }
      }
   },
   "compensating-operation":null
}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614862/how-can-i-beautify-json-programmatically

Comment: There's also http://www.jsonlint.com/ - if that'd help you by reducing your workload! :)

Comment: @limelights That looks like a good tool, but the arrays will always be valid so we don't need to test them, more just visualise them more neatly.

Comment: @RyanBrodie yeah, but i thought it visualized the array pretty neatly albeit not exactly like you wanted it.

Comment: @limelights We're dealign with a stream of arrays using HTML 5's web sockets, not just one, so otherwise that solution would of been perfect.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You may use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
JSON.stringify(jsonobj,null,'\t')
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wy2Uk/).

**UPDATE:** If you don't have `jsonobj`,but have json string,then before using `stringify` function,convert json string to json object by this line:

```
jsonobj = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
```

Comment: Not working - output is like `"{\"streamtype\":\"returnAll\"}`, as a string, with no line breaks or tabs.

Comment: @RyanBrodie You need to pass `Object`,not a `String`, that's why you got such results.  To convert string to object, use `JSON.parse(yourstring)`,and then pass to `JSON.stringify` function. So  you need to do this: `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(yourstring),null,'\t')`

Comment: does not work for me.  I try this and it's still not formatted:   $("#transactionResponse").show().html(JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'));  where data is the response json in my jQuery #.ajax() callback

Comment: Thanks @Engineer!