# Programmatically indent auto-generated code using php

Tags: php, javascript, indentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I beautify JSON programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614862/how-can-i-beautify-json-programmatically)

I have build a code generator that gives me a `.js` file as output with the javascript in it.
The code works fine but the only problem is for the indentation.

I have written my code generator in php.
Can anyone suggest me a library or something else that will help me to auto indent my generated code in php.

Comment: You might want to take a look as the [js-beautify library](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Thanks for that, i have written a php code that generates my `JS` code. so can you just guide me how can I use js-beautify library in my situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:
They have extensions, library, etc.

http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: the have extensions but most of them are browser based... anything that fits with php..

Comment: thanks i got the php code for jSbeauty.. it was there on there Github

Comment: no problem, yea well.... these kind of tools are good. some times we need them, usually I indent manually or depending environment I am using :)

Comment: actually i needed that beautifier for my code generator.. till now i was managing my code manually so that it gets indented but as the code generator matures..it will be difficult for me to manage code indentation manually.. thanks once again :)