# Json php formatting

Tags: php, json, pretty-print

I have json output written in php.

```
<?php
// parametri del database
$db_host = "<ip-address>";
$db_user = "<database user>";
$db_password = "<database password>";
$db_name = "<database name>";
$db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);
if ($db == FALSE)
die ("Errore nella connessione. Verificare i parametri..."); 
mysql_select_db($db_name, $db)
or die ("Errore nella selezione del database. Verificare i parametri...");
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM <nome tabella>");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

The "problem" is that is not formatting well but the output is in a single line.

`[{"id":"1","Nome":"Pippo","Cognome":"Paperino","mail":"pippo.paperino@disney.com","cell":"3333333333}]`

How can i display the output like:

```
{
    "a": "apple",
    "b": "banana",
    "c": "catnip"
}
```

?

i tryied using `echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` but doesn't work.. i wrote

`print(json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));` but i get an error.

Comment: Update your PHP version.

Comment: First, you need to post the error in your question, second `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` was only added in PHP 5.4 so you need to upgrade

Comment: It's first time i try to do something like this so maybe i wrong. Is there another way to formatting the json output instead using `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`?

Comment: Updated the php version but i display the same.. In one line.. I wrote: `echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Comment: http://recursive-design.com/blog/2008/03/11/format-json-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

First check with your json string its not a valid json. your json string should be:

```
[{"id":"1","Nome":"Pippo","Cognome":"Paperino","mail":"pippo.paperino@disney.com","cell":"3333333333"}]
```

You missed the double quote at the end in your json string.
You can check json is valid or not [here](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

And why do you want formatted output?

Comment: what i wrote is an example.. The data's aren't correct but invented because i can't write the right data output. Anyway i tryed to update the php version and i wrote: `echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` but doesn't work and it displays all in a single line again..

Comment: Ok. So for that Please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614862/how-can-i-beautify-json-programmatically