# How to have each record of JSON on a separate line?

Tags: java, json

When I use JSONArray and JSONObject to generate a JSON, whole JSON will be generated in one line. How can I have each record on a separate line?

It generates like this:

```
 [{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]
```

I need it to be like following:

```
 [{
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2"
    }]
```

Comment: You need to beautify/pretty print the JSON string which you have.

Comment: why you need like below one..both are same brother..

Comment: @Pavan to make it more readable, let say I have a JSON with 1 million records, I need to generate it check it and then use it.

Comment: What is the negative vote for? If you do not know why I have such requirement, you should not vote it negative. YOU should ask first.

Comment: @Jack, which json parsing library you are using ?

Comment: @SAM  I am using org.json.JSONArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Pretty Print JSON` Output (Jackson).

Bellow are some examples

1. Convert Object and print its output in JSON format.

   ```
    User user = new User();
    //...set user data
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(user));
   ```
2. Pretty Print JSON String

   ```
    String test = "{\"age\":29,\"messages\":[\"msg 1\",\"msg 2\",\"msg 3\"],\"name\":\"myname\"}";

    Object json = mapper.readValue(test, Object.class);    
    System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json));
   ```

Reference : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-enable-pretty-print-json-output-jackson/

Answer (score 2):

You may use of the `google-gson` library for beautifying your JSON string.
You can download the library from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Sample code :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement je = jp.parse(uglyJSONString);
String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
```

OR

you can use `org.json`

Sample code :

```
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(uglyJsonString); //tokenize the ugly JSON string
JSONObject finalResult = new JSONObject(tokener); // convert it to JSON object
System.out.println(finalResult.toString(4)); // To string method prints it with specified indentation.
```

Refer answer from this post :
[Pretty-Print JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105795/pretty-print-json-in-java)

Comment: This doesn't work for arrays (which was the original requirement).  It does pretty print objects with line breaks, but not objects contained within an outer array structure.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON.stringify method supported by many modern browsers (including IE8) can output a beautified JSON string:

```
JSON.stringify(jsObj, null, "\t"); // stringify with tabs inserted at each level
JSON.stringify(jsObj, null, 4);    // stringify with 4 spaces at each level
```

and please refer this :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2614874/3164682

you can also beautify your string online here.. http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer

Answer (score 0):

For gettting a easy to read json file you can configure the ObjectMapper to Indent using the following:

`objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);`