# How can I format a string to fix indentation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I am parsing a file in order to make some documentation.

The string I am being returned is:

```
"([ {
                href: "sass.html",
                text: "Sass"
            }, {
                href: "components.html",
                text: "Components"
            }, {
                href: "javascript.html",
                text: "Javascript"
            } ])
            "
```

I would like to prettify this so I can output it into a pre tag. So the ideal output would be something like this:

```
"(
  [
    {
      href: "sass.html",
      text: "Sass"
    },
    {
      href: "components.html",
      text: "Components"
    },
    {
      href: "javascript.html",
      text: "Javascript"
    }
  ]
)"
```

I am currently thinking I could remove all spacing in the string via:

```
string.replace(/\s/g,'')
```

Then do a bunch of splits to break each line apart and add spacing for indentation and rejoin it but this feels messy to me. Is there a better way I could so this?

Any advice is of course greatly appreciated.

This is different from: [How can I beautify JSON programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614862/how-can-i-beautify-json-programmatically) because i am dealing with a string on non-valid JSON.

Comment: Where is this formatting occurring? Does the object truly need to be indented?

Comment: @gon250 no it isn't.

Comment: @TheHippo: Apparently whoever stole the accepted answer to that question thought so too. Generally, if someone plagiarizes an accepted answer to an existing question, there is a very high chance the question being answered is a duplicate. It's clear that this is an exception to the rule however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty is that the format you have is strange, it is not valid JSON, so you can't use `JSON.parse()` directly.

It is not valid JSON for 2 reasons:

1. It is surrounded by `(` and `)` for some reason.
2. The keys are not double-quoted.

So what you ideally need to do is to convert the string into valid JSON first, then try and parse it.

A shortcut, if you are **sure** you trust this data, is to just get rid of the parentheses first and then use the much-vilified `eval()`, because it will get around the fact that the keys aren't quoted.

Here is the one-liner for that (assuming the string is in a variable called `s`):

```
JSON.stringify(eval(s.substring(s.indexOf('(') + 1, s.lastIndexOf(')'))), null, "\t")
```

Or to split it out a bit:

```
var pseudoJson = s.substring(s.indexOf('(') + 1, s.lastIndexOf(')'));
JSON.stringify(eval(pseudoJson), null, "\t");
```

Comment: Thanks for this it is almost perfect... the only issue is you are doing: eval(s) instead of eval(pseudoJson). I fixed that and it works great! Thanks again. If you fix that issue I will accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: @busyPixels Good spot. Fixed.