# How to create a proper json type data which has been fetched from nodejs mysql module?

Tags: php, mysql, json, node.js, sockets

Guys it's been a long time I have been working on my web project.I am creating a real time notification system for now and I am using `node js + socket io`.I am happy that with the help of expert people on `stackoverflow` I was able to work `apache server` and `nodejs server` on different `port` together working for one whole web application.Ok now let's go to the point.

With my logic guys I was trying to make a real time notification by two steps :-

1) First a user connect on socket via client side page then it `emit` connection event which is handled by our `nodejs` server file.

2) After detecting a user been connected on a socket I performed some `mysql` fetch inside that `nodejs` made server file like :-

```
// ....all module are presented here above...

io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
  var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "mydatabase"
  });

  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    var queryString = "Select * from table_one";
    connection.query(queryString, function(error, results) {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      } else {
        console.log("New client !");
        io.sockets.emit('u_d', results);
      }
    });
    connection.release();
  });
});
```

Above there I have used nodejs `mysql` module.It fetches all data from that table name `table_one` on `json` data type like in this picture below.

[image: Mysql fetched data retrieved on json format]

You can see I got my fetched data on `json` type.Is it possible to make my `json` data get in proper format like this :-

```
{
  "result": [{
      "id": "2",
      "user": "hari061",
      "pic": "img.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "user": "ram061",
      "pic": "nature.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

That json data will be handed to my client side here :-

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('u_d', function(data) {
  $('.display_noti').append($('<li style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;">').text(data));
});
```

After all this I found two problem :-

1) In each connection of a user `mysql` fetches data.(Which mean my user should connect on a socket every time for a new update).It will not be a real time I mean a page reload can only make that user connect on a socket back then only it will display him/her new update.

2) As I found `mysql` fetched data are retrieve on `json` format.I want to control the outcome of `json` format suitable for my client side.

how can I solve this two problem guys?

Answer (score 1):

If you modify data outside your server you can add some RESTful API to trigger server that data is updated:

```
# example with express.js
app.put '/newdata/', (req, res) ->
    get_updated_data (result) ->
        io.sockets.emit 'u_d', result       # send new update to all connected clients
```

At this logic when user connects you should send "last state" of data to new client:

```
io.sockets.on 'connection', (client) ->
    get_last_state (result) ->
        client.emit 'last state', result    # send last state to new client
```

Simple JSON formatting in one line:

```
JSON.stringify jsonObject, null, '\t'
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614862/how-can-i-beautify-json-programmatically) you can read more how to beautify JSON string.

Also, if you place connection call to MySQL outside of io's `connection` you'll save resources on MySQL connect/disconnect each time client connects to the socket.

Comment: I am confuse how can I make a user show notification update in real time?I mean I have fetched data from database and handed it on client but its working for one time only.How should server and client code work to achieve real time feature?

Comment: If you have access to code that changes data then you have to place there a request call (in npm see `request`) to let server know that your data has changed. Then you perform actions you need and send information about update to all connected clients.

In some cases it's enough to fetch table with some interval, compare to previous fetch result and send changes. But it's a bad choice in many ways.

Comment: I want such a logic bro I first wanna fetch some data from a table and emit those data back to the client.I then want if there is any new changes happens on that table it immediately emit again to the client so, that the user get new update in real time.Is there any way to to that bro?

Comment: Short answer — yes. Do you modify your table data on server or outside of the server?

Comment: why is it concern to modify bro?Can't i do some emit after i fetched data from database?You can see bro i'm trying to create emit after I fetched data from database.

Comment: Because fetching on connection will give you data in the moment. After that you have to know somehow that there is an update to send it to client.

Comment: ok  then @iw2rmb what will be the best idea to make it work??

Comment: To answer that I need to know where and how your data is modifying?

Comment: ok then bro i got what you mean.I guess i should emit when ever some user create some action right?

Comment: Yes. But you need to be more specific in your questions.

Comment: Can u edit my question title bro if you understand what i mean.