# ngModel for textarea not working in angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular

I am trying to print json object in textarea using `ngModel`.

I have done following:

```
<textarea style="background-color:black;color:white;" [(ngModel)]='rapidPage' rows="30" cols="120">                             
</textarea>
```

I want to load the json object in textarea. The above code is loading the `rapidPage` object in textarea but its showing textarea value as `[object Object]`.

object:

```
 this.rapidPage = {            
        "pageRows": [
            {
                "sections": [
                    {
                        "sectionRows": [
                            {
                                "secRowColumns": [                                       
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "secRowColumns": [
                                    {
                                        "colName": "users"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "secRowColumns": [
                                    {
                                        "colName": "sample"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "width": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "pageName": "DefaultPage",
        "pageLayout": "DEFAULT_LAYOUT",
        "editMode": true
    };
```

I want to load the data as string.
any inputs?

Comment: `rapidPage.key` target the key in the object. can you post the object?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Assuming that you want to bind `rapidPage` as it is and will only write valid JSON in the textArea.

- You need to `PARSE` it when changing the value, and `STRINGIFY` when showing in textarea.

---

[**StackBlitz DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wyfnas)

Do the following in your Component code

```ts
  rapidPage = {"pageRows":[{"sections":[{"sectionRows":[{"secRowColumns":[]},{"secRowColumns":[{"colName":"users"}]},{"secRowColumns":[{"colName":"sample"}]}],"width":0}]}],"pageName":"DefaultPage","pageLayout":"DEFAULT_LAYOUT","editMode":true}; 
  // your object

  get rapidPageValue () {
    return JSON.stringify(this.rapidPage, null, 2);
  }

  set rapidPageValue (v) {
    try{
    this.rapidPage = JSON.parse(v);}
    catch(e) {
      console.log('error occored while you were typing the JSON');
    };
  }
```

Template Usage:

```ts
<textarea [(ngModel)]='rapidPageValue' rows="30" cols="120">                             
</textarea>
```

Comment: i got the output correctly.thanks.is there any way to indent this json object because series of characters is too mainstream.

Comment: you'll have to use a code beutifier plugin of some short to achieve that, I haven't done anything like this before, there might be some `api`s too that might provide you with formatted json on just one api call.

Comment: beautification is possible with JSON.stringify as well, I updated my answer and plunker. see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614862/how-can-i-beautify-json-programmatically) too.

Comment: Already did that. :) I am novice in angular2,if possible can you share any details of your social profile.would like to learn from you. :)

Comment: Unrealistically true, I am not active on any social network anymore, But I visit stackoverflow everyday. You can just post your questions and I'll try my best. you can find my mail on SO profile. Thanks for your kind consideration, but SO has much more talented  and active people than me.

Answer (score 22):

```html
<textarea class="form-control" 
          name="message"
          rows="8"
          [(ngModel)]="Obj.message"
          #message='ngModel'
          ></textarea>
```

for Two way binding You just need to add attribute in textarea tag `name="message"`,  ONLY `[(ngModel)]` works 100%!.

Comment: Great answer. A bit strange, but apparently the `[(ngModel)]` thing doesn't work without a `name` attribute. - Having said that, I found the `#message='ngModel'` in your answer a bit confusing, as this seems unnecessary and seems to make no difference.

Comment: my text area [formControl] binding didn't work until I added name attribute. thanks!

Comment: I agree with @ihorbond. Same for me.

Comment: Not working on Angular 9, here is my error message : 

`Cannot assign value "$event" to template variable "message". Template variables are read-only.`

Answer (score 14):

For binding textarea values in Angular 2 you can use the change-function:

## Template

```
<textarea id="some-value" (change)="doTextareaValueChange($event)">{{textareaValue}}</textarea>
```

## Component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private textareaValue = '';
  doTextareaValueChange(ev) {
    try {
      this.textareaValue = ev.target.value;
    } catch(e) {
      console.info('could not set textarea-value');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

ngModel works if

1. There is a form wrapped around it & textarea has a name attribute added to it.

If you not you can use the following syntax to achieve the same effect

```
<textarea [value]="strVariableInComponent" (input)="strVariableInComponent = $event.target.value;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you! The fact that ngModel only works inside a form is what I was missing.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you really want to have sync in between, you would normally implement a button to save/apply the change when it's finished json editing. If that is the case, your render is easy.

```
<textarea #textbox>{{ rapidPage | json }}</textarea>
```

Make sure no other space or return character in between the above line.

Then an traditional button, ex.

```
<a (click)="updateRapidPage(textbox.value)">Apply</a>
```

I found this is better in some case than brutal `[(rapidPage)]`.

You can also use `@ViewChild('textbox') input` inside the component to access this variable.

Comment: Great answer! This is simple and easily works. No funny ([ngModel]) business.

Answer (score 2):

Can you test with this:

```
<textarea #textbox (change)="text = textbox.value" style="width:100%;">{{ text }}</textarea>
```

Regards

Comment: An explanation as to why this code works or what changes you had to make and why would be helpful to the person who originally asked the question.

Comment: Should have added a fiddle with your code. This is not even an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation [()] is for two way syntax sugar to remove the boilerplate. What event is being invoked at this? Irrespective, you can put a string output also alongwith the event in below code

Probably try the below code implemetation for your string output

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel]',
  host: {
    "[value]": 'ngModel',
    "(input)": "ngModelChange.next($event.target.value)"
  }
})
class NgModelDirective {
  @Input() ngModel:any; // stored value
  @Output() ngModelChange:EventEmitter; = new EventEmitter() // an event emitter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `stringify`  your json and use in the ngModel like this -

```
<textarea style="height:100px; width:300px;background-color:black;color:white;" [(ngModel)]='rapidPage' rows="30" cols="120">
    </textarea>

ArrayDemo: Array<any> = [{"name":"pardeep","last":"jain"}]
  rapidPage = JSON.stringify(this.ArrayDemo);
```

Working Example <kbd>[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/hw8Bh3JQXK9e8OM0OL8g?p=preview)</kbd>

Browser shows `[object object]` because angular unables to parse the JSON the asign the value in ngModel you must need a string
so convert this using `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 0):

I find that importing `FormsModule` from `@angular/forms` solves the issue.

In `app.module.ts`

```js
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    FormsModule
  ],
...
})
```