# Use get/set on NgModule binding angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class with a field that is a JSON object and I need to display this JSON into a textarea. So I have create a set/get method to handle this beavior.

My Class:

```
class Element {

 property: string;
 value: string;

  constructor(property: string,value: string){

    this.property = property;
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class Model {

   elements: Element[];

   constructor(elements?: Element) { 
       this.elements = elements;
   }

   get elementsValue() {
       return JSON.stringify(this.elements, null, 2);
   }
   set elementsValue(value: string) {
       this.elements = JSON.parse(value);
   }

}
```

My component:

```
  @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      providers: [],
      template: `
        <div *ngFor="let model of models">
             <textarea [(ngModel)]='model.elementsValue' rows="30" cols="120"></textarea>
        </div>  `,
      directives: []
    })
    export class App {

      models = [
          new Model([new Element("test","value"),new Element("test","value")]),
          new Model()
      ]
    }
```

The `elementsValue` value is not bound to the textarea. The textarea is empty

I have use [this Plank](http://plnkr.co/edit/3BWfSgO1Dg7Xpfn9pgWF?p=preview) as template.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What more specifically is happening? And is it possible to change the Plunker to demonstrate *your* issue. That would help us help you.

Comment: the Plunker is not mine. I have use it as a template

Comment: Yes, but you can click the button in the upper left corner to fork the plunker and then add your code. It would be easier to help you if we can see your code in the context of a running plunker.

Comment: where is your rapidPage variable? I do not see any references to your Objects variable. Check out this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346820/ngmodel-for-textarea-not-working-in-angular2

Comment: Do you have to use get/set properties?

And you are not creating instant of "Object" (object) when you do 
"new Model();"

Solution would be, creating proper "Object" with properties in Model, instead of doing json stringify or parse.

Comment: Finally, I have found the problem, I create the `Model` as a result of remote API calling like `res.json() as Model`, this way not ceate an instance of the `Model` so `get` end `set` not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="object of objects">
```

Try

```
<div *ngFor="let object of objects">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `constructor` in the `Model` class expects just a single `Element` as argument. Try to change that parameter to an array of elements

```
constructor(elements?: Element[]) {
   this.elements = elements;
}
```