# How to convert string which is output of select .....from for JSON AUTO to JSON Formatted file which is readable without using third party tool SSIS

Tags: sql, json, ssis, ssis-2016

HI I am writing SSIS package to get the output from
`Select a,b,c from CUST FOR JSON AUTO`
However I am getting output  in a single row like

{"a":"Rock" ,"b":"paper" ,"c":"scissors"},  {"a":"Rock" ,"b":"paper" ,"c":"scissors"},  {"a":"Rock" ,"b":"paper" ,"c":"scissors"}....

However I want output as

```
{ 
 "a":"Rock",
  "b":"paper",
  "c":"scissors"
 },
 
{ 
 "a":"Rock",
  "b":"paper",
  "c":"scissors"
 },
 
{ 
 "a":"Rock",
  "b":"paper",
  "c":"scissors"
 },
```

My client argument is the Json file will be big file and he don't want to do extra formatting and should be readable

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a javascript component to SSIS, it can be done.
(I'm not sure on how to do that in SSIS). But here is [how you do it in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614862/how-can-i-beautify-json-programmatically)

I have a way to get this done rather *messy* way, but you can see whether that serves you the purpose

```
DECLARE @nl varchar(2) = char(13), @Json nvarchar(MAX) = (Select a,b,c from #CUST FOR JSON AUTO) 

Select @Json = Replace(@Json, '[{','[' + @nl + '{' + @nl) 
Select @Json = Replace(@Json, '{','{' + @nl) 
Select @Json = Replace(@Json, '","','",' + @nl + '"' ) 
Select @Json = Replace(@Json, '"},{','"' + @nl + '},' + @nl + @nl + '{' ) 
Select @Json = Replace(@Json, '"}]','"' + @nl + '}' + @nl + ']' + @nl + @nl) 

Select @Json as FormattedJSON
```

And here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b697cd294a4a7cee36384420cfa91f03) with more improvements

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I am not looking for Java script.i am looking if we can do it in SSIS or sql

Comment: @hrishi, my friend, first you should read the answer fully. The solution given here is SQL. Did you try it?