# How to style/format JSON response and display it in user readable format?

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch-api, stringify

I'm working on a personal project , A postman clone.
I'm using fetch API to fetch the data and then using JSON.stringify() to convert that into string and display it inside a "textarea" which is the "Response" field as you can see below.
Came across an answer-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614862/how-can-i-beautify-json-programmatically , but it doesn't seems to work for me.

> How can I format the json object or the string and display it inside the "Response" tab ?

[image: PostMan Response]

```
**Here is the html code for the response field**
<div class="responseBox">
    Response
    <textarea class="responseText" id="responseId" ></textarea>
</div>

**JS code for fetching the response using Fetch API and displaying it in Response field :** 
const response = await fetch(url);
console.log("Fetching data...");
const e = await response.json();
console.log(e);
responseId.innerText=JSON.stringify(e);

**CSS for response field :** 
.responseText{
width: 705px;
height: 350px;
position: relative;
right: 255px;
white-space: pre;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the answer you have [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614862/how-can-i-beautify-json-programmatically) suggests, the `JSON.stringify` function supports formatting JSON strings, which is how you should format JSON strings.

```js
JSON.stringify(jsObj, null, "\t"); // stringify with tabs inserted at each level
JSON.stringify(jsObj, null, 4);    // stringify with 4 spaces at each level
```

Comment: I figured it out .
I had to use ** responseId.innerHTML=`${JSON.stringify(e,null,"\t")}`  ** instead of ** responseId.innerText=JSON.stringify(e,null,"\t") **