# JavaScript: How can I generate formatted easy-to-read JSON straight from an object?

Tags: javascript, json, formatting, pretty-print

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [How can I beautify JSON programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614862/how-can-i-beautify-json-programmatically)

I know how to generate JSON from an object using JSON.stringify, or in my case the handy *[jQuery JSON](https://github.com/krinkle/jquery-json)* from [Google Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Developers#Google_Code).

Now this works fine, but the output is hard to read for humans.  Is there an easy way, function, or whatever to output a neatly formatted JSON file?

This is what I mean:

```
JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2,c:{d:1,e:[1,2]}});
```

gives...

```
"{"a":1,"b":2,"c":{"d":1,"e":[1,2]}}"
```

I'd like something like this instead:

```
{
 "a":1,
 "b":2,
 "c":{
    "d":1,
    "e":[1,2]
 }
}
```

E.g., with newlines and tabs added. It's much easier to read for larger documents.

I'd like to do this ideally without adding any huge libraries, for example, not [Prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework), [YUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_UI_Library), or whatever.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Now you know why many prefer XML instead of JSON. Its much more readable.

Comment: @HermanVanDerBlom, a one-line XML would not be human readble either.

Answer (score 1236, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` takes more [optional arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Parameters).

Try:

```
 JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2,c:{d:1,e:[1,2]}}, null, 4); // Indented 4 spaces
 JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2,c:{d:1,e:[1,2]}}, null, "\t"); // Indented with tab
```

From:

*[How can I beautify JSON programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614862/json-beautifier)*

It should work in modern browsers, and it is included in [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) if you need a fallback for browsers that don't support the JSON helper functions. For display purposes, put the output in a `<pre>` tag to get newlines to show.

Comment: Isn't this answer a bit inaccurate given the OP wrote his beautified version with the `"e":[1,2]` all on one line? Is it possible to mix indented & non-indented JSON with stringify?

Comment: Just remember to put it inside something like <pre> to get new lines.

Comment: https://github.com/Phrogz/NeatJSON and https://npm.io/package/json-beautify privide some more control & options for programmatic stringification of JSON.

Comment: You can use `white-space: pre` instead of a `<pre>`, if you prefer.