# JQuery quickly dump object's members

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there was a quick way to get all of an object's variable's values, similar to php's `var_dump()` method.

So if I had an object

```
var myObject = {
    Up: 38,
    Dn: 40,
    Lf: 37,
    Rt: 39,
    Enter: 13,
    Space: 32,
    Esc: 27
};
```

The string I would get back would look something like

```
[ Up:38, Dn:40, Lf:37, Rt:39, Enter:13, Space:32, Esc:27 ]
```

Let's say I need to do this on a computer where I can't use firebug. Is there any way to do this without iterating through all the parameters in an object? Is there a standalone library that has something like this?

Comment: @FelixKling not a JSON object, would it still work?

Comment: @Hans. There is no such thing a JSON object.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` converts arrays and objects to JSON. Nothing more, nothing less. Regarding gdoron's comment, have a look at http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @FelixKling Oh wow, I guess I haven't really worked with JSON before... that's really interesting

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an equivalent for var_dump (PHP) in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323517/is-there-an-equivalent-for-var-dump-php-in-javascript) -- provides a list of possibilities (also my suggestion).

Comment: Hmm JSON.stringify seems to work on objects that aren't handles/don't have handles to jquery selected elements.

Comment: @FelixKling I tried the methods mentioned in that post, but it doesn't work for me. I think I'll try forking to a different question.

Comment: Mmmh. The accepted answer seems to be ok. But yeah, if you have complex objects, it's coing to be more difficult. Then you should really use Firebug Lite.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a quick one liner I often use

```
   var o = {a:1, b:2}, k, s = []; for (k in o) o.hasOwnProperty(k) && s.push (o[k]); s = s.join (', ');
```

You only need to change one occurence of the object (value of o) and the result is in s.

This does not recurse into the data structure. JSON.stringify is probably more suited if that is a requirement. Note however that JSON.stringify does not do functions, it simply skips them!

For formatted stringify use

```
JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2,c:{d:1,e:[1,2]}}, null, 4); // Indented 4 spaces
```

As per answer to [Javascript: How to generate formatted easy-to-read JSON straight from an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515523)

Answer (score 5):

Using the default dev. tools on IE, Chrome and Firefox

```
console.dir(myObject);
```

If you really can't use these tools then maybe a `JSON.stringify(myObject)` could help.

Comment: "Let's say I need to do this on a computer where I can't use firebug."

Comment: No dev tools can be used at all? Look into JSON.stringify.

Comment: Right, on IE console.dir dumps all the info of the object but console.log doesn't. On Chrome, console.log works fine. I'll edit the answer to include that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [FirebugLite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) ? It has a lot of Firebug functions.

This is Javascript Firebug library, you need only to load script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
```

And you will get Firebug console in all major browsers including Internet Explorer

Comment: I can't use Firebug at all, I'm not using a computer I can install things on, so I'm stuck developing on IE.

Comment: @Hans FirebugLite is a Javascript library, look at my link

Comment: Please, don't post answers with links only, it's useless if the links rot.

Comment: For the record, IE has a serviceable set of developer's tools that includes a console.  So, console.log would work for this....nothing to install.

Answer (score 1):

**JSON.stringify** is the way to go, but it works on all browsers, just include the lib:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Example:

```
        text = JSON.stringify(['e', {pluribus: 'unum'}]);
        // text is '["e",{"pluribus":"unum"}]'


        text = JSON.stringify(['e', {pluribus: 'unum'}], null, '\t');
        // text is '[\n\t"e",\n\t{\n\t\t"pluribus": "unum"\n\t}\n]'

        text = JSON.stringify([new Date()], function (key, value) {
            return this[key] instanceof Date ?
                'Date(' + this[key] + ')' : value;
        });
        // text is '["Date(---current time---)"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function var_dump(obj) {
    var obj_members = "";
    var sep = "";
    for (var key in obj) {
        obj_members += sep + key + ":" + obj[key];
        sep = ", ";
    }
    return ("[" + obj_members + "]");
}
```