# How to show json into client like this

Tags: php, json

How to show json into client like this link

https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global

Comment: `json_encode` returns a JSON string - just echo that. Is there some other detail I'm missing?

Comment: What exactly do yo mean?

Comment: do you mean to output json string in a formatted way?

Comment: while i use json_encode, the browser shows a string, and the format is only one line, not like the link.
i am confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) option:

```
$data = Array( 
    "Foo" => "Bar",
    "Fiz" => "Buz"
);

echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This requires PHP 5.4.0 or greater. The output follows:

```
{
    "Foo": "Bar",
    "Fiz": "Buz"
}
```

Comment: echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);  can use in PHP 5.3.0?

Comment: @jiemoon PHP 5.3 does **not** support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about indentation, right? If you are, you should notice that this json output is surrounded by a `<pre>` tag and it's filled with blank spaces to separate the pieces of data:

```
{     "data": [         {             "canonical_url": "https://alpha.app.net/marcozehe/post/2172854",
```

Did you try to replicate that? You can also check this other question:
[Javascript: How to generate formatted easy-to-read JSON straight from an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515523/javascript-how-to-generate-formatted-easy-to-read-json-straight-from-an-object)

just checking: you are not talking about the REST-like URL, are you?

Comment: yeah.so how can i do it?