# Magento Json encode with new lines (pretty/carriage return)

Tags: json, magento, printing, encode

I encode array to json and get

```
{"payment_providers":[{"name":"ccsave","revenue":[{"date":"2013-03-18","sales":"51.00","items":"2","median_item_price":"20.50"}]},{"name":"checkmo","revenue":[{"date":"2013-03-18","sales":"79.00","items":"5","median_item_price":"8.00"}]},...
```

But I need:

```
{
    "payment_providers":[
       {"name":"ccsave",
        "revenue":[
            {"date":"2013-03-18","sales":"51.00","items":"2","median_item_price":"20.50"}
         ]
        },
        {"name":"checkmo","revenue":[
           {"date":"2013-03-18","sales":"79.00","items":"5","median_item_price":"8.00"}
         ]
        }, ...
```

How can I get Json looks pretty?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/json-pretty-print-using-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515523/javascript-how-to-generate-formatted-easy-to-read-json-straight-from-an-object

Comment: I'm looking for the way to do it in PHP ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a PHP function json-encode, check documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

and also check similar question here: [Pretty-Printing JSON with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php)