# How to render object that pass through props in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render the data (object) that comes through props. However, I have got the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` Some how, I do not know why the data or object is null although the state of the `data` is updated during `componentDidMount()`. Would you help me why the data is null?

Please look `class A` to see how the data is consumed

```
class A extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.data = this.props.location.state.data;
    this.setState({ data: this.props.location.state.data });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(this.data).map((key, index) => (
          <p key={index}> value is {this.data[key]}</p>
        ))}
        hello
      </div>
    );
  }
}

A.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.object,
  location: PropTypes.object
};
export default A;
```

Assume, `this.data` contains the data in the following format

```
{
    id: 1,
    userName: "ABDXY",
    date: "01/12/2020",
    time: "21:00"
}
```

Comment: `this.data` is null or undefined, and you get the error when you call `Object.keys` on it. This has nothing to do with React or JSX.

Comment: Why are you using `this.data` instead of using `this.state.data`?

Comment: add this.data as a property in state and then use it from this.state, or use this.props.location.state.data directly in Object.keys()

Comment: may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515523/javascript-how-to-generate-formatted-easy-to-read-json-straight-from-an-object) is what you want

Comment: @Ernesto instead of using `this.props.location.state.data` . How can I assign or change the state of `data` to `this.props.location.state.data`. So that I can use `data` in the iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.data` is not defined. You can access the data that is set in the state using `this.state.data`

Please ensure that `this.props.location.state.data` is not null

```
class A extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // this.data = this.props.location.state.data;  => not required.
    this.setState({
      data: this.props.location.state.data
    });
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div > {
        Object.keys(this.state.data).map((key, index) => ( < 
          p key = {
            index
          } > value is {
            this.state.data[key]
          } < /p>
        ))
      }
      hello <
      /div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work as it is but if you change `null` to `{}` it works. Please update your answer

Comment: Cool. Will improve my answer. But that shouldn't be a problem i think.

Answer (score 0):

Get data from state instead of `this.data` since it will not trigger render when `this.data` will update. Also use `{}` as default value

```
class A extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const data = {
      id: 1,
      userName: "ABDXY",
      date: "01/12/2020",
      time: "21:00"
    };
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(data).map((key, index) => (
          <p key={index}> value is {data[key]}</p>
        ))}
        hello
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default A;
```