# pretty-print JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, pretty-print

How can I display JSON in an easy-to-read (for human readers) format? I'm looking primarily for indentation and whitespace, with perhaps even colors / font-styles / etc.

Comment: If you're just outputting to html, you can wrap it in a ```<pre>``` tag.

Comment: all answer will work but you have to use  javascript ::  var str = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);   in html // <pre  id="output_result_div"></pre >

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)` to format data, then use [AceEditor](https://ace.c9.io/), [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/), or [Monaco Editor](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor) to display it.

Answer (score 6753, accepted):

**[Pretty-printing is implemented natively in `JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)**. The third argument enables pretty printing and sets the spacing to use:

```
var str = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2); // spacing level = 2
```

If you need syntax highlighting, you might use some regex magic like so:

```
function syntaxHighlight(json) {
    if (typeof json != 'string') {
         json = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 2);
    }
    json = json.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function (match) {
        var cls = 'number';
        if (/^"/.test(match)) {
            if (/:$/.test(match)) {
                cls = 'key';
            } else {
                cls = 'string';
            }
        } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
            cls = 'boolean';
        } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
            cls = 'null';
        }
        return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + match + '</span>';
    });
}
```

See in action here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KJQ9K/554/)

**Or a full snippet provided below:**

```js
function output(inp) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = inp;
}

function syntaxHighlight(json) {
    json = json.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function (match) {
        var cls = 'number';
        if (/^"/.test(match)) {
            if (/:$/.test(match)) {
                cls = 'key';
            } else {
                cls = 'string';
            }
        } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
            cls = 'boolean';
        } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
            cls = 'null';
        }
        return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + match + '</span>';
    });
}

var obj = {a:1, 'b':'foo', c:[false,'false',null, 'null', {d:{e:1.3e5,f:'1.3e5'}}]};
var str = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4);

output(str);
output(syntaxHighlight(str));
```

```css
pre {outline: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; }
.string { color: green; }
.number { color: darkorange; }
.boolean { color: blue; }
.null { color: magenta; }
.key { color: red; }
```

Comment: Super awesome. I added a function to pop open this in a new window for debugging:   var json = syntaxHighlight(JSON.stringify(obj,undefined,4););
    var w = window.open();
    var html = "<head><style>pre {outline: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; } .string { color: green; } ";
        html+= " .number { color: darkorange; } .boolean { color: blue; } .null { color: magenta; } .key { color: red; }</style></head><body>";
    html+= "<pre>"+json+"</pre>";
    w.document.writeln(html);

Comment: Nice. Don't forget it needs css and a `<pre>`, though.

Comment: Note that `stringify(...)` works on JSON *objects*, not on JSON strings. If you have a string, you need to `JSON.parse(...)` first

Comment: i built a tool on this https://sardapv.github.io/json-prettier/ :)

Comment: Hello, this is awesome.  It works but I get a lint warning on the second-to-last backslash in the regex-   Unnecessary escape character: \-  no-useless-escape. I don't have it unit tested so afraid to // eslint-disable-next-line

Comment: In the `syntaxHighlight` function could you add the `<details>` tag for child objects? That would be really useful for big JSON objects

Comment: Unfortunately it works pretty poorly.  For instance, it doesn't add the spacing to the closing brace, making it impossible to get properly indented output.  It'll work fine if you're including the output of this function on column 0.  But the moment you want to indent it in, it becomes problematic.  Also, double quotes.

Answer (score 425):

User Pumbaa80's answer is great if you have an **object** you want pretty printed. If you're starting from a valid JSON **string** that you want to pretty printed, you need to convert it to an object first:

```
var jsonString = '{"some":"json"}';
var jsonPretty = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonString),null,2);
```

This builds a JSON object from the string, and then converts it back to a string using JSON stringify's pretty print.

Comment: Note that when displaying the string you need to wrap it in `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: It seems to only work when using textarea, otherwise the newlines don't come in

Answer (score 127):

Better way.

[Prettify JSON Array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359291/prettify-json-array-in-javascript)

```
JSON.stringify(jsonobj,null,'\t')
```

Comment: this was great. and as a tip, load the result in `<pre>RESULT</pre>` to see formatted in html page too.

Answer (score 68):

I think you're looking for something like this :

```
JSON.stringify(obj, null, '\t');
```

This "pretty-prints" your JSON string, using a tab for indentation.

If you prefer to use spaces instead of tabs, you could also use a number for the number of spaces you'd like :

```
JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
```

Answer (score 65):

```
var jsonObj = {"streetLabel": "Avenue Anatole France", "city": "Paris 07",  "postalCode": "75007", "countryCode": "FRA",  "countryLabel": "France" };

document.getElementById("result-before").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

In case of displaying in HTML, you should to add a balise `<pre></pre>`

```
document.getElementById("result-after").innerHTML = "<pre>"+JSON.stringify(jsonObj,undefined, 2) +"</pre>"
```

Example:

```js
var jsonObj = {"streetLabel": "Avenue Anatole France", "city": "Paris 07",  "postalCode": "75007", "countryCode": "FRA",  "countryLabel": "France" };

document.getElementById("result-before").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

document.getElementById("result-after").innerHTML = "<pre>"+JSON.stringify(jsonObj,undefined, 2) +"</pre>"
```

```css
div { float:left; clear:both; margin: 1em 0; }
```

```html
<div id="result-before"></div>
<div id="result-after"></div>
```

Answer (score 45):

Based on Pumbaa80's answer I have modified the code to use the console.log colours (working on Chrome for sure) and not HTML. Output can be seen inside console. You can edit the _variables inside the function adding some more styling.

```
function JSONstringify(json) {
    if (typeof json != 'string') {
        json = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, '\t');
    }

    var 
        arr = [],
        _string = 'color:green',
        _number = 'color:darkorange',
        _boolean = 'color:blue',
        _null = 'color:magenta',
        _key = 'color:red';

    json = json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function (match) {
        var style = _number;
        if (/^"/.test(match)) {
            if (/:$/.test(match)) {
                style = _key;
            } else {
                style = _string;
            }
        } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
            style = _boolean;
        } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
            style = _null;
        }
        arr.push(style);
        arr.push('');
        return '%c' + match + '%c';
    });

    arr.unshift(json);

    console.log.apply(console, arr);
}
```

Here is a bookmarklet you can use:

```
javascript:function JSONstringify(json) {if (typeof json != 'string') {json = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, '\t');}var arr = [],_string = 'color:green',_number = 'color:darkorange',_boolean = 'color:blue',_null = 'color:magenta',_key = 'color:red';json = json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function (match) {var style = _number;if (/^"/.test(match)) {if (/:$/.test(match)) {style = _key;} else {style = _string;}} else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {style = _boolean;} else if (/null/.test(match)) {style = _null;}arr.push(style);arr.push('');return '%c' + match + '%c';});arr.unshift(json);console.log.apply(console, arr);};void(0);
```

Usage:

```
var obj = {a:1, 'b':'foo', c:[false,null, {d:{e:1.3e5}}]};
JSONstringify(obj);
```

Edit: I just tried to escape the % symbol with this line, after the variables declaration:

```
json = json.replace(/%/g, '%%');
```

But I find out that Chrome is not supporting % escaping in the console. Strange... Maybe this will work in the future.

Cheers!

[image]

Answer (score 35):

You can use `console.dir()`, which is a shortcut for `console.log(util.inspect())`.
(The only difference is that it bypasses any custom `inspect()` function defined on an object.)

It uses **syntax-highlighting**, **smart indentation**, **removes quotes from keys** and just makes the output as pretty as it gets.

```
const object = JSON.parse(jsonString)

console.dir(object, {depth: null, colors: true})
```

and for the command line:

`cat package.json | node -e "process.stdin.pipe(new stream.Writable({write: chunk => console.dir(JSON.parse(chunk), {depth: null, colors: true})}))"`

Answer (score 28):

I use the [JSONView Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc) (it is as pretty as it gets :):

Edit: added `jsonreport.js`

I've also released an online stand-alone JSON pretty print viewer, jsonreport.js, that provides a human readable HTML5 report you can use to view any JSON data.

You can read more about the format in *[New JavaScript HTML5 Report Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/HTML5ReportFormat)*.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using ES5, simply call JSON.stringify with:

- 2nd arg: replacer; set to null,
- 3rd arg: space; use tab.

```
JSON.stringify(anObject, null, '\t');
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 17):

Here's [user123444555621's awesome HTML one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220510) adapted for terminals. Handy for debugging Node scripts:

```
function prettyJ(json) {
  if (typeof json !== 'string') {
    json = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 2);
  }
  return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, 
    function (match) {
      let cls = "\x1b[36m";
      if (/^"/.test(match)) {
        if (/:$/.test(match)) {
          cls = "\x1b[34m";
        } else {
          cls = "\x1b[32m";
        }
      } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
        cls = "\x1b[35m"; 
      } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
        cls = "\x1b[31m";
      }
      return cls + match + "\x1b[0m";
    }
  );
}
```

Usage:

```
// thing = any json OR string of json
prettyJ(thing);
```

Answer (score 13):

Unsatisfied with other pretty printers for Ruby, I wrote my own ([NeatJSON](http://github.com/Phrogz/NeatJSON)) and then [ported it to JavaScript](https://github.com/Phrogz/NeatJSON/blob/master/javascript/neatjson.js) including [a free online formatter](http://phrogz.net/js/neatjson/neatjson.html). The code is free under MIT license (quite permissive).

Features (all optional):

- Set a line width and wrap in a way that keeps objects and arrays on the same line when they fit, wrapping one value per line when they don't.
- Sort object keys if you like.
- Align object keys (line up the colons).
- Format floating point numbers to specific number of decimals, without messing up the integers.
- 'Short' wrapping mode puts opening and closing brackets/braces on the same line as values, providing a format that some prefer.
- Granular control over spacing for arrays and objects, between brackets, before/after colons and commas.
- Function is made available to both web browsers and Node.js.

I'll copy the source code here so that this is not just a link to a library, but I encourage you to go to the [GitHub project page](http://github.com/Phrogz/NeatJSON), as that will be kept up-to-date and the code below will not.

```js
(function(exports){
exports.neatJSON = neatJSON;

function neatJSON(value,opts){
  opts = opts || {}
  if (!('wrap'          in opts)) opts.wrap = 80;
  if (opts.wrap==true) opts.wrap = -1;
  if (!('indent'        in opts)) opts.indent = '  ';
  if (!('arrayPadding'  in opts)) opts.arrayPadding  = ('padding' in opts) ? opts.padding : 0;
  if (!('objectPadding' in opts)) opts.objectPadding = ('padding' in opts) ? opts.padding : 0;
  if (!('afterComma'    in opts)) opts.afterComma    = ('aroundComma' in opts) ? opts.aroundComma : 0;
  if (!('beforeComma'   in opts)) opts.beforeComma   = ('aroundComma' in opts) ? opts.aroundComma : 0;
  if (!('afterColon'    in opts)) opts.afterColon    = ('aroundColon' in opts) ? opts.aroundColon : 0;
  if (!('beforeColon'   in opts)) opts.beforeColon   = ('aroundColon' in opts) ? opts.aroundColon : 0;

  var apad  = repeat(' ',opts.arrayPadding),
      opad  = repeat(' ',opts.objectPadding),
      comma = repeat(' ',opts.beforeComma)+','+repeat(' ',opts.afterComma),
      colon = repeat(' ',opts.beforeColon)+':'+repeat(' ',opts.afterColon);

  return build(value,'');

  function build(o,indent){
    if (o===null || o===undefined) return indent+'null';
    else{
      switch(o.constructor){
        case Number:
          var isFloat = (o === +o && o !== (o|0));
          return indent + ((isFloat && ('decimals' in opts)) ? o.toFixed(opts.decimals) : (o+''));

        case Array:
          var pieces  = o.map(function(v){ return build(v,'') });
          var oneLine = indent+'['+apad+pieces.join(comma)+apad+']';
          if (opts.wrap===false || oneLine.length<=opts.wrap) return oneLine;
          if (opts.short){
            var indent2 = indent+' '+apad;
            pieces = o.map(function(v){ return build(v,indent2) });
            pieces[0] = pieces[0].replace(indent2,indent+'['+apad);
            pieces[pieces.length-1] = pieces[pieces.length-1]+apad+']';
            return pieces.join(',\n');
          }else{
            var indent2 = indent+opts.indent;
            return indent+'[\n'+o.map(function(v){ return build(v,indent2) }).join(',\n')+'\n'+indent+']';
          }

        case Object:
          var keyvals=[],i=0;
          for (var k in o) keyvals[i++] = [JSON.stringify(k), build(o[k],'')];
          if (opts.sorted) keyvals = keyvals.sort(function(kv1,kv2){ kv1=kv1[0]; kv2=kv2[0]; return kv1<kv2?-1:kv1>kv2?1:0 });
          keyvals = keyvals.map(function(kv){ return kv.join(colon) }).join(comma);
          var oneLine = indent+"{"+opad+keyvals+opad+"}";
          if (opts.wrap===false || oneLine.length<opts.wrap) return oneLine;
          if (opts.short){
            var keyvals=[],i=0;
            for (var k in o) keyvals[i++] = [indent+' '+opad+JSON.stringify(k),o[k]];
            if (opts.sorted) keyvals = keyvals.sort(function(kv1,kv2){ kv1=kv1[0]; kv2=kv2[0]; return kv1<kv2?-1:kv1>kv2?1:0 });
            keyvals[0][0] = keyvals[0][0].replace(indent+' ',indent+'{');
            if (opts.aligned){
              var longest = 0;
              for (var i=keyvals.length;i--;) if (keyvals[i][0].length>longest) longest = keyvals[i][0].length;
              var padding = repeat(' ',longest);
              for (var i=keyvals.length;i--;) keyvals[i][0] = padRight(padding,keyvals[i][0]);
            }
            for (var i=keyvals.length;i--;){
              var k=keyvals[i][0], v=keyvals[i][1];
              var indent2 = repeat(' ',(k+colon).length);
              var oneLine = k+colon+build(v,'');
              keyvals[i] = (opts.wrap===false || oneLine.length<=opts.wrap || !v || typeof v!="object") ? oneLine : (k+colon+build(v,indent2).replace(/^\s+/,''));
            }
            return keyvals.join(',\n') + opad + '}';
          }else{
            var keyvals=[],i=0;
            for (var k in o) keyvals[i++] = [indent+opts.indent+JSON.stringify(k),o[k]];
            if (opts.sorted) keyvals = keyvals.sort(function(kv1,kv2){ kv1=kv1[0]; kv2=kv2[0]; return kv1<kv2?-1:kv1>kv2?1:0 });
            if (opts.aligned){
              var longest = 0;
              for (var i=keyvals.length;i--;) if (keyvals[i][0].length>longest) longest = keyvals[i][0].length;
              var padding = repeat(' ',longest);
              for (var i=keyvals.length;i--;) keyvals[i][0] = padRight(padding,keyvals[i][0]);
            }
            var indent2 = indent+opts.indent;
            for (var i=keyvals.length;i--;){
              var k=keyvals[i][0], v=keyvals[i][1];
              var oneLine = k+colon+build(v,'');
              keyvals[i] = (opts.wrap===false || oneLine.length<=opts.wrap || !v || typeof v!="object") ? oneLine : (k+colon+build(v,indent2).replace(/^\s+/,''));
            }
            return indent+'{\n'+keyvals.join(',\n')+'\n'+indent+'}'
          }

        default:
          return indent+JSON.stringify(o);
      }
    }
  }

  function repeat(str,times){ // http://stackoverflow.com/a/17800645/405017
    var result = '';
    while(true){
      if (times & 1) result += str;
      times >>= 1;
      if (times) str += str;
      else break;
    }
    return result;
  }
  function padRight(pad, str){
    return (str + pad).substring(0, pad.length);
  }
}
neatJSON.version = "0.5";

})(typeof exports === 'undefined' ? this : exports);
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use `JSON.stringify(your object, null, 2)`
The second parameter can be used as a replacer function which takes key and Val as parameters.This can be used in case you want to modify something within your JSON object.

more reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 12):

For debugging purpose I use:

```js
console.debug("%o", data);
```

- https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console

Answer (score 9):

Quick pretty human-readable JSON output in 1 line code (without colors):

```js
document.documentElement.innerHTML='<pre>'+JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)+'</pre>';
```

Comment: Best out of the box solution :+1:

Answer (score 8):

Thanks a lot @all!
Based on the previous answers, here is another variant method providing custom replacement rules as parameter:

```
 renderJSON : function(json, rr, code, pre){
   if (typeof json !== 'string') {
      json = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, '\t');
   }
  var rules = {
   def : 'color:black;',    
   defKey : function(match){
             return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>';
          },
   types : [
       {
          name : 'True',
          regex : /true/,
          type : 'boolean',
          style : 'color:lightgreen;'
       },

       {
          name : 'False',
          regex : /false/,
          type : 'boolean',
          style : 'color:lightred;'
       },

       {
          name : 'Unicode',
          regex : /"(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?/,
          type : 'string',
          style : 'color:green;'
       },

       {
          name : 'Null',
          regex : /null/,
          type : 'nil',
          style : 'color:magenta;'
       },

       {
          name : 'Number',
          regex : /-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/,
          type : 'number',
          style : 'color:darkorange;'
       },

       {
          name : 'Whitespace',
          regex : /\s+/,
          type : 'whitespace',
          style : function(match){
             return '&nbsp';
          }
       } 

    ],

    keys : [
       {
           name : 'Testkey',
           regex : /("testkey")/,
           type : 'key',
           style : function(match){
             return '<h1>' + match + '</h1>';
          }
       }
    ],

    punctuation : {
          name : 'Punctuation',
          regex : /([\,\.\}\{\[\]])/,
          type : 'punctuation',
          style : function(match){
             return '<p>________</p>';
          }
       }

  };

  if('undefined' !== typeof jQuery){
     rules = $.extend(rules, ('object' === typeof rr) ? rr : {});  
  }else{
     for(var k in rr ){
        rules[k] = rr[k];
     }
  }
    var str = json.replace(/([\,\.\}\{\[\]]|"(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function (match) {
    var i = 0, p;
    if (rules.punctuation.regex.test(match)) {
               if('string' === typeof rules.punctuation.style){
                   return '<span style="'+ rules.punctuation.style + '">' + match + '</span>';
               }else if('function' === typeof rules.punctuation.style){
                   return rules.punctuation.style(match);
               } else{
                  return match;
               }            
    }

    if (/^"/.test(match)) {
        if (/:$/.test(match)) {
            for(i=0;i<rules.keys.length;i++){
            p = rules.keys[i];
            if (p.regex.test(match)) {
               if('string' === typeof p.style){
                   return '<span style="'+ p.style + '">' + match + '</span>';
               }else if('function' === typeof p.style){
                   return p.style(match);
               } else{
                  return match;
               }                
             }              
           }   
            return ('function'===typeof rules.defKey) ? rules.defKey(match) : '<span style="'+ rules.defKey + '">' + match + '</span>';            
        } else {
            return ('function'===typeof rules.def) ? rules.def(match) : '<span style="'+ rules.def + '">' + match + '</span>';
        }
    } else {
        for(i=0;i<rules.types.length;i++){
         p = rules.types[i];
         if (p.regex.test(match)) {
               if('string' === typeof p.style){
                   return '<span style="'+ p.style + '">' + match + '</span>';
               }else if('function' === typeof p.style){
                   return p.style(match);
               } else{
                  return match;
               }                
          }             
        }

     }

    });

  if(true === pre)str = '<pre>' + str + '</pre>';
  if(true === code)str = '<code>' + str + '</code>';
  return str;
 }
```

Comment: @manking ... rules = $.extend(rules, ('object' === typeof rr) ? rr : {});  ... it is to extend the ruleset by an rulset object. (maybe you find updates: https://github.com/frdl/-Flow/blob/master/api-d/4/js-api/library.js/core/plugin.core.js#L9142 )

Answer (score 8):

It works well:

```
console.table()
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Console/table

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple JSON format/color component written in React:

```
const HighlightedJSON = ({ json }: Object) => {
  const highlightedJSON = jsonObj =>
    Object.keys(jsonObj).map(key => {
      const value = jsonObj[key];
      let valueType = typeof value;
      const isSimpleValue =
        ["string", "number", "boolean"].includes(valueType) || !value;
      if (isSimpleValue && valueType === "object") {
        valueType = "null";
      }
      return (
        <div key={key} className="line">
          <span className="key">{key}:</span>
          {isSimpleValue ? (
            <span className={valueType}>{`${value}`}</span>
          ) : (
            highlightedJSON(value)
          )}
        </div>
      );
    });
  return <div className="json">{highlightedJSON(json)}</div>;
};
```

See it working in this CodePen:
https://codepen.io/benshope/pen/BxVpjo

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

Couldn't find any solution that had good syntax highlighting for the console, so here's my 2p

### Install & Add cli-highlight dependency

```
npm install cli-highlight --save //or use "yarn add"
```

### Define logjson globally

```
const highlight = require('cli-highlight').highlight
console.logjson = (obj) => console.log(
                               highlight( JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4), 
                                          { language: 'json', ignoreIllegals: true } ));
```

### Use

```
console.logjson({foo: "bar", someArray: ["string1", "string2"]});
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 6):

Here's something to spruce up this oldie but goodie question.
What if you want to dump a formatted object to console but it keeps dumping like a wrapped mess with hidden chars like this???

```
'{\n    "_id": "630577bba145ff4f1",\n    "role": "user"}'
```

But you want this loveliness??:

```
{
    "_id": "630557672d877bba145ff4f1",
    "role": "user"
}
```

The trick is To wrap your JSON.stringify() in a console.log() statement.
If you hate typing, try building the snippet to do the heavy lifting...

This is really useful if you're working with big objects.

add a snippet to your 'Snippets' section in browser dev tools like this ([more...](https://dev.to/sstores/using-snippets-in-devtools-563c)):

```
let o = <object to print>
console.log(JSON.stringify(o, null, 4))
console.log(o)
```

then simply replace  with your object (which will be available from the current context) and run the snippet.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a nice library to prettify json on a web page...

Prism.js is pretty good.

http://prismjs.com/

I found using JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2) to get the indentation, and then using prism to add a theme was a good approach.

If you're loading in JSON via an ajax call, then you can run one of Prism's utility methods to prettify

For example:

```
Prism.highlightAll()
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to show my `jsonAnalyze` method here, it does a **pretty print of the JSON structure only**, but in some cases can be more usefull that printing the whole JSON.

Say you have a complex JSON like this:

```
let theJson = {
'username': 'elen',
'email': 'elen@test.com',
'state': 'married',
'profiles': [
    {'name': 'elenLove', 'job': 'actor' },
    {'name': 'elenDoe', 'job': 'spy'}
],
'hobbies': ['run', 'movies'],
'status': {
    'home': { 
        'ownsHome': true,
        'addresses': [
            {'town': 'Mexico', 'address': '123 mexicoStr'},
            {'town': 'Atlanta', 'address': '4B atlanta 45-48'},
        ]
    },
    'car': {
        'ownsCar': true,
        'cars': [
            {'brand': 'Nissan', 'plate': 'TOKY-114', 'prevOwnersIDs': ['4532354531', '3454655344', '5566753422']},
            {'brand': 'Benz', 'plate': 'ELEN-1225', 'prevOwnersIDs': ['4531124531', '97864655344', '887666753422']}
        ]
    }
},
'active': true,
'employed': false,
};
```

Then the method will return the structure like this:

```
username
email
state
profiles[]
    profiles[].name
    profiles[].job
hobbies[]
status{}
    status{}.home{}
        status{}.home{}.ownsHome
        status{}.home{}.addresses[]
            status{}.home{}.addresses[].town
            status{}.home{}.addresses[].address
    status{}.car{}
        status{}.car{}.ownsCar
        status{}.car{}.cars[]
            status{}.car{}.cars[].brand
            status{}.car{}.cars[].plate
            status{}.car{}.cars[].prevOwnersIDs[]
active
employed
```

So this is the `jsonAnalyze()` code:

```
function jsonAnalyze(obj) {
        let arr = [];
        analyzeJson(obj, null, arr);
        return logBeautifiedDotNotation(arr);

    function analyzeJson(obj, parentStr, outArr) {
        let opt;
        if (!outArr) {
            return "no output array given"
        }
        for (let prop in obj) {
            opt = parentStr ? parentStr + '.' + prop : prop;
            if (Array.isArray(obj[prop]) && obj[prop] !== null) {
                    let arr = obj[prop];
                if ((Array.isArray(arr[0]) || typeof arr[0] == "object") && arr[0] != null) {                        
                    outArr.push(opt + '[]');
                    analyzeJson(arr[0], opt + '[]', outArr);
                } else {
                    outArr.push(opt + '[]');
                }
            } else if (typeof obj[prop] == "object" && obj[prop] !== null) {
                    outArr.push(opt + '{}');
                    analyzeJson(obj[prop], opt + '{}', outArr);
            } else {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof obj[prop] != 'function') {
                    outArr.push(opt);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function logBeautifiedDotNotation(arr) {
        retStr = '';
        arr.map(function (item) {
            let dotsAmount = item.split(".").length - 1;
            let dotsString = Array(dotsAmount + 1).join('    ');
            retStr += dotsString + item + '\n';
            console.log(dotsString + item)
        });
        return retStr;
    }
}

jsonAnalyze(theJson);
```

Answer (score 4):

Douglas Crockford's JSON in JavaScript library will pretty print JSON via the stringify method.

You may also find the answers to this older question useful: [How can I pretty-print JSON in (unix) shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-to-pretty-print-json-script)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into an issue today with @Pumbaa80's code. I'm trying to apply JSON syntax highlighting to data that I'm rendering in a [Mithril](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril/) view, so I need to create DOM nodes for everything in the `JSON.stringify` output.

I split the really long regex into its component parts as well.

```coffee
render_json = (data) ->
  # wraps JSON data in span elements so that syntax highlighting may be
  # applied. Should be placed in a `whitespace: pre` context
  if typeof(data) isnt 'string'
    data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2)
  unicode =     /"(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?/
  keyword =     /\b(true|false|null)\b/
  whitespace =  /\s+/
  punctuation = /[,.}{\[\]]/
  number =      /-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/

  syntax = '(' + [unicode, keyword, whitespace,
            punctuation, number].map((r) -> r.source).join('|') + ')'
  parser = new RegExp(syntax, 'g')

  nodes = data.match(parser) ? []
  select_class = (node) ->
    if punctuation.test(node)
      return 'punctuation'
    if /^\s+$/.test(node)
      return 'whitespace'
    if /^\"/.test(node)
      if /:$/.test(node)
        return 'key'
      return 'string'

    if /true|false/.test(node)
      return 'boolean'

     if /null/.test(node)
       return 'null'
     return 'number'
  return nodes.map (node) ->
    cls = select_class(node)
    return Mithril('span', {class: cls}, node)
```

Code in context on Github [here](https://github.com/justjake/squidwork/blob/f0ed0a2dd25f5182ae792da0695e46ec86a665f9/squidwork/web/monitor/templates/app.coffee#L48)

Answer (score 4):

If you need this to work in a textarea the accepted solution will not work.

`<textarea id='textarea'></textarea>`

`$("#textarea").append(formatJSON(JSON.stringify(jsonobject),true));`

```
function formatJSON(json,textarea) {
    var nl;
    if(textarea) {
        nl = "&#13;&#10;";
    } else {
        nl = "<br>";
    }
    var tab = "&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;";
    var ret = "";
    var numquotes = 0;
    var betweenquotes = false;
    var firstquote = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var c = json[i];
        if(c == '"') {
            numquotes ++;
            if((numquotes + 2) % 2 == 1) {
                betweenquotes = true;
            } else {
                betweenquotes = false;
            }
            if((numquotes + 3) % 4 == 0) {
                firstquote = true;
            } else {
                firstquote = false;
            }
        }

        if(c == '[' && !betweenquotes) {
            ret += c;
            ret += nl;
            continue;
        }
        if(c == '{' && !betweenquotes) {
            ret += tab;
            ret += c;
            ret += nl;
            continue;
        }
        if(c == '"' && firstquote) {
            ret += tab + tab;
            ret += c;
            continue;
        } else if (c == '"' && !firstquote) {
            ret += c;
            continue;
        }
        if(c == ',' && !betweenquotes) {
            ret += c;
            ret += nl;
            continue;
        }
        if(c == '}' && !betweenquotes) {
            ret += nl;
            ret += tab;
            ret += c;
            continue;
        }
        if(c == ']' && !betweenquotes) {
            ret += nl;
            ret += c;
            continue;
        }
        ret += c;
    } // i loop
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is nice:

https://github.com/mafintosh/json-markup from `mafintosh`

```
const jsonMarkup = require('json-markup')
const html = jsonMarkup({hello:'world'})
document.querySelector('#myElem').innerHTML = html
```

HTML

```
<link ref="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<div id="myElem></div>
```

Example stylesheet can be found here

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mafintosh/json-markup/master/style.css
```

Answer (score 2):

To highlight and beautify it in `HTML` using `Bootstrap`:

```
function prettifyJson(json, prettify) {
    if (typeof json !== 'string') {
        if (prettify) {
            json = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 4);
        } else {
            json = JSON.stringify(json);
        }
    }
    return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g,
        function(match) {
            let cls = "<span>";
            if (/^"/.test(match)) {
                if (/:$/.test(match)) {
                    cls = "<span class='text-danger'>";
                } else {
                    cls = "<span>";
                }
            } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
                cls = "<span class='text-primary'>";
            } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
                cls = "<span class='text-info'>";
            }
            return cls + match + "</span>";
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!-- here is a complete example pretty print with more space between lines-->
<!-- be sure to pass a json string not a json object -->
<!-- use line-height to increase or decrease spacing between json lines -->

<style  type="text/css">
.preJsonTxt{
  font-size: 18px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 200%;
}
.boxedIn{
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>

<div class="boxedIn">
    <h3>Configuration Parameters</h3>
    <pre id="jsonCfgParams" class="preJsonTxt">{{ cfgParams }}</pre>
</div>

<script language="JavaScript">
$( document ).ready(function()
{
     $(formatJson);

     <!-- this will do a pretty print on the json cfg params      -->
     function formatJson() {
         var element = $("#jsonCfgParams");
         var obj = JSON.parse(element.text());
        element.html(JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2));
     }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

based on [@user123444555621](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220510), just slightly more modern.

```
const clsMap = [
    [/^".*:$/, "key"],
    [/^"/, "string"],
    [/true|false/, "boolean"],
    [/null/, "key"],
    [/.*/, "number"],
]

const syntaxHighlight = obj => JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)
    .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
    .replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, match => `<span class="${clsMap.find(([regex]) => regex.test(match))[1]}">${match}</span>`);
```

you can also specify the colors inside js (no CSS needed)

```
const clsMap = [
    [/^".*:$/, "red"],
    [/^"/, "green"],
    [/true|false/, "blue"],
    [/null/, "magenta"],
    [/.*/, "darkorange"],
]

const syntaxHighlight = obj => JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)
    .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
    .replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, match => `<span style="color:${clsMap.find(([regex]) => regex.test(match))[1]}">${match}</span>`);
```

and a version with less regex

```
const clsMap = [
    [match => match.startsWith('"') && match.endsWith(':'), "red"],
    [match => match.startsWith('"'), "green"],
    [match => match === "true" || match === "false" , "blue"],
    [match => match === "null", "magenta"],
    [() => true, "darkorange"],
];
    
const syntaxHighlight = obj => JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)
    .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
    .replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, match => `<span style="color:${clsMap.find(([fn]) => fn(match))[1]}">${match}</span>`);
```

Answer (score 1):

it's for Laravel, Codeigniter
Html:
`<pre class="jsonPre"> </pre>`

Controller: Return the JSON value from the controller as like as

`return json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

In script:
`<script> $('.jsonPre').html(result); </script>`

result will be

[image: result will be]

Answer (score 1):

With Typescript now, you can attach custom functions to global objects.

- remember to declare in the main index file at the top

**index.ts**

```
declare global {
  interface JSON {
    prettyPrint: (obj: any) => void;
  }
}

JSON.prettyPrint = function (obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
};
```

**other files**

```
JSON.prettyPrint({ a: 1, b: 3 })
```

**prints**

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can print without using native function.

```
function pretty(ob, lvl = 0) {

  let temp = [];

  if(typeof ob === "object"){
    for(let x in ob) {
      if(ob.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        temp.push( getTabs(lvl+1) + x + ":" + pretty(ob[x], lvl+1) );
      }
    }
    return "{\n"+ temp.join(",\n") +"\n" + getTabs(lvl) + "}";
  }
  else {
    return ob;
  }

}

function getTabs(n) {
  let c = 0, res = "";
  while(c++ < n)
    res+="\t";
  return res;
}

let obj = {a: {b: 2}, x: {y: 3}};
console.log(pretty(obj));

/*
  {
    a: {
      b: 2
    },
    x: {
      y: 3
    }
  }
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to display an object for debugging purposes:

```
console.log("data",data) // lets you unfold the object manually
```

If you want to display the object in the DOM, you should consider that it could contain strings that would be interpreted as HTML.  Therefore, you need to [do some escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35735254/86967)...

```
var s = JSON.stringify(data,null,2) // format
var e = new Option(s).innerHTML // escape
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<pre>'+e+'</pre>') // display
```