# pretty printing in cljs

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am trying to pretty print a JSON from clojurescript, on the browser's console.

I found the following link - [How can I pretty-print JSON using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/json-pretty-print-using-javascript)

The above link provides the following js - `JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2)`

The following translation in cljs doesnt work `(.stringify js/JSON obj undefined 2)`

1. Is there any native way in cljs for pretty printing?
2. Any ideas why the above cljs expression doesnt work ?

Comment: What you get when you use `(.stringify js/JSON obj undefined 2)`?

Comment: What is ```obj```? If it's a clojure map you'll need to convert it to a js object first.

Comment: Does ClojureScript understand `undefined`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE**: ClojureScript now has a full port of clojure.pprint in the form of cljs.pprint.

There's also a [fipp](https://github.com/brandonbloom/fipp) which is narrower in scope and likely a bit faster.

Comment: ClojureScript has two pretty-printers available:

https://github.com/shaunlebron/cljs-pprint

https://github.com/brandonbloom/fipp

Answer (score 5):

```
cljs.user> (.stringify js/JSON (clj->js {:foo 42}) nil 2)
"{\n  \"foo\": 42\n}"

cljs.user> (pr-str {:foo 42})
"{:foo 42}"
```

Answer (score 4):

The following converts a Clojure map (`object`) to JSON and prints it in the console as an object that can hence leverage the browsers inspect JSON functionality:

```clj
(.dir js/console (clj->js object))
```

**EDIT**: While pretty printing is really nice, in the developer console I still prefer the ability to browse the data structure as a tree and now frequently use [cljs-devtools](https://github.com/binaryage/cljs-devtools). It is a library that gives you an interactive data tree that can be expanded as a normal js-object but for vanilla clojure without having to convert to js, meaning `:keywords`, `{:ma "ps"}` and the rest of the clj-family.

At the moment it requires you to add a leiningen dependency and some code to your project and to use Chrome Canary.

Answer (score 2):

`clojure.pprint` has been ported to ClojureScript with release `0.0-3255`. It is called `cljs.pprint`.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, someone needs to port `clojure.pprint`, which seems to be going on here [`shaunlebron/cljs-pprint`](https://github.com/shaunlebron/cljs-pprint).

In the mean time, if you are running on NodeJS, I use `prettyjson` from npm.

```
(ns foo (:require [cljs.nodejs :as nodejs]
                  [cljs.core :refer [clj->js]]))
(nodejs/enable-util-print!)
(def render (.-render (nodejs/require "prettyjson")))
(defn pp [value] (println (render (clj->js value))))
```

It then prints the value in *colorised* YAML:

```
ClojureScript:foo> (pp {:a 123 :foo ["baz" 42]})
a:   123
foo:
  - baz
  - 42
```

This is just a hack, but at least is is readable.