# How to use JSON.parse or eval () to display an array?

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, jplayer

I have this code to save values ​​in json string in a session variable, which I call from ajax

I have the following code:

```
(function ($) { 

    Drupal.behaviors.MyfunctionTheme = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {

     $('.add-music').click(function () {
         var songNew = JSON.stringify({
             title: $(this).attr('data-title'),
             artist: $(this).attr('data-artist'),
             mp3: $(this).attr('href')
         });
         var songIE = {json:songNew};
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             data: songIE,
             datatype: 'json',
             async: true,
             cache: false                
         })
         .done(
              //this is the callback function, which will run when your POST request returns
            function(postData){
                //Make sure to test validity of the postData here before issuing the GET request
                var session;
                $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
                $.get('/getsession.php', function (getData) {
                      session = getData;
                        alert(session);
                });

              }
         );

     });

}}

})( jQuery );
```

I have the following code that works fine, I just printed the following alert:

```
["{\"title\":\"El Derecho de las Mujeres a La Comunicaci\u00f3n\",\"artist\":\"\",\"mp3\":\"http:\/\/red.comppa.com\/sites\/default\/files\/audios\/Cun%CC%83aDerechoMujeresaLaComunicacion.mp3\"}","{\"title\":\"Objetivos del encuentro internacional de Derechos Humanos en el Bajo Aguan.\",\"artist\":\"\",\"mp3\":\"http:\/\/red.comppa.com\/sites\/default\/files\/audios\/objetivos_del_encuentro_dh.mp3\"}"]
```

and I need to have something like this:

```
[
  {
    title:"Cro Magnon Man",
    artist:"The Stark Palace",
    mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3"
  },
  {
    title:"Hidden",
    artist:"Miaow",
    mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-02-Hidden.mp3"
  }
]
```

How I can work this data with jquery?

thank's

Comment: `JSON.parse(somevar)` should do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/json-pretty-print-using-javascript

Comment: The data should come back as JSON (and *automatically converted* to a JS object graph by jQuery) .. or not. Why is it a "string in some variable"? That's just icky ..

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data is stored in a variable called `yourObject` you can do:

```
var result = JSON.parse("["+yourObject[0]+"]");
```

[Here is a working bin](http://jsbin.com/uzavus/1/edit)

Comment: Why are you adding `[` and `]`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's what he asked for in his input/result. He already has the JSON serialization of the inside of the array in a string, and that string as the first and only element of an array.

Comment: instead of using var result = , you can "alert(JSON.parse("["+yourObject[0]+"]");

Answer (score 0):

This is what `JSON.parse()` was designed to do. `Eval()` is not the approach to use here. To clarify, `JSON.parse()` takes valid, appropriately escaped JSON strings and converts them into usable objects within Javascript. `eval()`, on the other hand, is designed to take strings and attempt to EXECUTE them as Javascript functions, objects, variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample input is actually an array of strings. You need to parse each element within the array as an object. Using jQuery:

```
var input = ["{\"title\":\"El Derecho de las Mujeres a La Comunicaci\u00f3n\",\"artist\":\"\",\"mp3\":\"http:\/\/red.comppa.com\/sites\/default\/files\/audios\/Cun%CC%83aDerechoMujeresaLaComunicacion.mp3\"}","{\"title\":\"Objetivos del encuentro internacional de Derechos Humanos en el Bajo Aguan.\",\"artist\":\"\",\"mp3\":\"http:\/\/red.comppa.com\/sites\/default\/files\/audios\/objetivos_del_encuentro_dh.mp3\"}"];

var resultArray = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    var parsedElement = $.parseJSON(input[i]);
    resultArray.push(parsedElement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var display = JSON.stringify(jsonObject, undefined, 2); // indentation level = 2
```

Comment: This will display pretty string