# Display Json String in html with correct indention

Tags: html, json, indentation

My server side will return a JSON string and I need to display it at my Html page.
So lets say the string is something like this:

```
{"FirstChildType":{"FirstGrandChild":{"GrandChildName":"123"},"FirstChildName":"a"},"SecondChildType":{"SecondChildName":"SecondChildABC","SecondChildLastName":"SecondChildXYZ"},"ThirdChildType":null,"FirstName":"ABC","LastName":"XYZ"}
```

How do I show this in my Html with a nice indention? I tried 'google-code-prettify' but somehow couldn't get this to work like I wanted.

Comment: Any requirement ? Use JavaScript only?? Can use PHP ??

Comment: Yes, can. Javascript or any client side library. I want to display it something like syntax highlighter, but with correct indention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page here answers it well with [JSON.stringfy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript). See it in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KJQ9K/)

```
            function syntaxHighlight(json) {
                if (typeof json != 'string') {
                     json = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 2);
                }
                json = json.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
                return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function (match) {
                    var cls = 'number';
                    if (/^"/.test(match)) {
                        if (/:$/.test(match)) {
                            cls = 'key';
                        } else {
                            cls = 'string';
                        }
                    } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
                        cls = 'boolean';
                    } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
                        cls = 'null';
                    }
                    return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + match + '</span>';
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to format it :

```
var jsParsed = {"FirstChildType":{"FirstGrandChild":{"GrandChildName":"123"},"FirstChildName":"a"},"SecondChildType":{"SecondChildName":"SecondChildABC","SecondChildLastName":"SecondChildXYZ"},"ThirdChildType":null,"FirstName":"ABC","LastName":"XYZ"};        
var indented = JSON.stringify(g,null,4);
```