# API Json output - scraping web content

Tags: json, api

I'm a beginner at JSON and using APIs. The code below is to put a business page on to my website.

```
{
 "response_info": { "status": "ok" },
 "title": "Item title", 
 "id": "https://www.gov.uk/api/business-finance-support-finder.json", 
 "web_url": "https://www.gov.uk/business-finance-support-finder",
 "details": {"key": "value"},
 "tags": [
      {"id": "ID", 
       "type": "Section", 
       "title": "Tag Name", 
       "web_url": ""}
    ],
 "related_artefacts": []
}
```

I just need to get that displayed on to my website, I'm confused as to how i should go about this?

I've tried many different ways but i've come up short. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pretty-print JSON using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This question is often asked. Please see this example of a good solution, using javascript as part of your HTML.

[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220510/2327328)

Comment: Hi i've looked at that answer and I still don't no how i'd go about it, im a complete novice when it comes to this. thanks

Comment: you add javascript to your HTML and then the javascript reads and prints the JSON: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_howto.asp