# Display a pretty json on an html div..possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I already read this topic [How can I pretty-print JSON using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript)

anyway the correct answer just works if I want to print that json to the console.

Doing something like

```
$("#myDiv").text(parsedJson);
```

or

```
$("#myDiv").html(parsedJson);
```

will not result in a pretty json.

My intention is to display a dialog box containing that json object, in an human readable form..is it possible?

Comment: Whomever voted to close this as "too broad":  How in the world is this question "too broad"?  It's very specific, has a clear focus, and clarifying code as to what was tried and what is being attempted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/pretty-print-json-using-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Untested, but should get you started:

```
$('#myDiv').append(
    $('<pre>').text(
        JSON.stringify(parsedJson, null, '  ')
    )
);
```

Comment: it's work perfectly with JSON object.

When i try with XML object then it will not work so do you have solution for XML object ?

Comment: @HirenTailor Imagine that... an answer about serializing an object as JSON outputs JSON.  You should post a separate question with whatever it is that you're trying to do.  This question is totally unrelated.

Comment: yes i know @brad and i thought may be you have some idea about it so that's why i ask you in comment.

Comment: @HirenTailor StackOverflow works different than other sites.  Separate questions should be posted as separate questions, rather than taking existing questions and answers off-topic.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `<pre>` tag instead of `div`, assuming `parsedJson` contains all newlines and indentation.