# How can I pretty-print JSON text on the fly on a web page?

Tags: css, json, format

I have a HTML5 application built using Twitter Bootstrap and JQuery (core).

It is a test/demo front-end for a REST-based service API.

In this application, I would like to show the JSON being received. On the page, that is. Not the console.

I would like to format the JSON (pretty-print) to be a bit more HUMAN-readable.

Is there an easy way to do this using HTML, JavaScript, and CSS? Is there a component I can use?

In addition, but not so important, I would like to give the user the ability to enter the JSON that makes up the request body. Is there a way that I can validate the JSON on the fly. Again, using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript?

**Update**: This question *is* a duplicate, and can be closed. It has been answered elsewhere - I should be using `JSON.parse()` followed by `JSON.stringify(...)` - `stringify()` works on JSON *objects*, not JSON text strings, hence the need to `parse()` first

Comment: you can use that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript

Comment: As far as validation (which should be a separate question), you'd take the text (from a `textarea`, etc.) and run it through `JSON.parse()` within a `try ... catch` block to see if any errors were thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a library called [Swagger](https://helloreverb.com/developers/swagger) before. It has most of the components separated out into individual libraries but this [Demo](http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/#!/pet/partialUpdate) shows how it looks when connected.

The library will print the JSON in a pretty format and it allows for people to enter different request information. It may be a little heavy for what you need but some of the libraries may be useful.