# Modifying a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON generated by Papa Parse from a CSV file that look like this:

```
{ object, object, object, .... , object }
```

I need to modify it so it looks like this:

```
{ "publication" : 
    {
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "name1"
    },
  "publication" :
    {
      "id" : 2,
      "name" : "name2"
    },
  "publication" :
    {
      "id" : 3,
      "name" : "name3"
    }
}
```

Where the "id" and "name" are properties within each object.

In other words, I need a JSON that say "publication" and each "publication" occurrence have nested under it the properties names and values of one of the objects above.

How could I achieve this with Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Described structure is not possible. You can only have one property with the key Publication.

Comment: You can't have several things with the same key.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to have things with the same key since there would be ambiguity ... what would `data.publication` return? name1? name2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript - you would parse your json, iterate through it and rebuild it as needed.

Comment: +1 to @dfsq. You are probably looking for an array that looks something like `{publications : [ { "id": 1, ...}, ... ] }`

Comment: Ok. I'm really new to all of this. Maybe my system can accept to have all the objects under one key "publication". I will try this construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot put many keys with same name...

a solution it's put in array

```
{ 
    "publication" : [
      {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "name1"
      },
      {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "name2"
      },
      {
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "name3"
      }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this not an array of publications?

```
   { publications: [{"id":1, "name":"name1"},
         {"id":2, "name":"name2"}.....]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right, you probably mean that you have objects like this:

```
{"publication" : { "id" : 1, "name" : "name1" }
{"publication" : { "id" : 2, "name" : "name2" }
{"publication" : { "id" : 3, "name" : "name3" }
```

What you can do in order to have:

```
{ "publication" : [ 
    {
        "id" : 1, 
        "name" : "name1"
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 1, 
        "name" : "name2"
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 3, 
        "name" : "name3"
    } ] 
}
```

is:

```
var json = [{"publication" : { "id" : 1, "name" : "name1" }},
                {"publication" : { "id" : 2, "name" : "name2" }},
                {"publication" : { "id" : 3, "name" : "name3" }}];

var newJson = {"publication" : []};

    var i = 0;
    for (var item in json) {
        var key = json[item];
        var obj = {"id" : key["publication"]["id"], "name" : key["publication"]["name"]};
        newJson["publication"][i] = obj;
        i++;
    }
```

You can check this if you want to print "pretty":

[How can I pretty-print JSON using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript)