# Dynamic creation of JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create a JSON of the following format dynamically using JavaScript. I have tried to do this, but it is so nested I am getting errors all the time. Could you please help me with this?

```
    {
     "name": "flare",
     "children": [
       {
         "name": "analytics",
        "children": [
         {
           "name": "cluster",
           "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
      ]
      }
     ]
    }
   ]}
```

It is a part of the same structure, and itself repeats over again and again. Please help me with this.

Comment: have you tried `JSON.parse` ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7220510/667599

Comment: no,i am trying to create a new son of the above format.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var output = [];
function processJson(parent) { 
    var retVal = {
        "name": parent.name            
    };
    parent.find("children").each(function() {
        if (!retVal.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
            retVal.children = [];
        }
        retVal.children.push(processJson($(this)));
    });
    return retVal;
}


$.each(input, function(i, item) {
  output.push(processJson(input[i]));
});​
```

At last print json `JSON.stringify(output)`

Answer (score 0):

Following function can be used to create each node

```
function Node(obj){
 $.extend(this,obj);
 this.children = [];
 this.addChild=function(obj){
   var temp = new Node(obj); 
  this.children.push(temp);
  return temp;
 }
}
```

Now creating tree dynamically is easier

```
var tree = new Node({});
tree
.addChild({name:'flare'})
.addChild({name:'analytics'})
.addChild({name:'cluster'})
.addChild({name: "AgglomerativeCluster", size: 3938})
```

You can add children to each node.