# using the javascript \r\n\ in a variable in an MVC view pulling from the @model

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to get formatting right for the Ace (Ajax.org Cloud9 Editor) so I am parsing through the Json pulled from the @Model in an MVC view like so:

```
var model = JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));

var comma = model.replace(/,/g, ",\r\n");
var curlyBracket = comma.replace(/{/g, "{\r\n");
var colonCurlyBracket = bracket.replace(/:{/g, ':\r\n\{');
var bracketCurlyBracket = colonCurlyBracket.replace(/:\[{/g, ':\r\n\[{');

editor.setValue(bracketCurlyBracket, -1);
```

The problem is this doesn't do any indents to keep the formatting correct, it just puts carriage returns and new lines.  I tried using:

```
var comma = model.replace(/,/g, ",\r\n\"); 
var curlyBracket = comma.replace(/{/g, "{\r\n\"); 
var colonCurlyBracket = bracket.replace(/:{/g, ':\r\n\\{'); 
var bracketCurlyBracket = colonCurlyBracket.replace(/:\[{/g, ':\r\n\\[{');
```

but the extra "\" gives me the error "Unterminated string constant" on the first two lines and on the second two lines it just adds a "\" to the editor.  I need the lines to continue so that the indents get put in and the formatting works.  How do I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to pretty-print the json?  [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript)

Comment: No.  Just need the formatting to look proper so it's easier to read.

Comment: Please look at the third parameter for JSON.stringify, that might do it all for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to James here's the answer:

The third parameter for JSON.stringify accomplishes the task of formatting properly so it should look like this:

```
var model = JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)), null, ' ');
editor.setValue(model, -1);
```

The 3rd parameter (' ') takes spaces and the number of spaces determines the number of indents (I.E. 3 spaces = 3 indents):

```
"filters": [
            {
                "id": "LastName",
                "label": "LastName",
                "type": "string",
                "operators": [
                    "equal",
                    "not_equal",
                    "begins_with",
                    "not_begins_with",
                    "contains",
                    "not_contains",
                    "ends_with",
                    "not_ends_with"
                ]
            }
           ]
```

Hope this helps someone else.