# How to see a json object's format?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using Django as back-end,in my view.py I return a json object as

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result))
```

and in my front-end, in a javascript file I received with

```
jsonResult = JSON.parse(result);
```

it is successful cause I can see the variable "jsonResult" if I use the console to check it, just as:

```
console.log(jsonResult);
```

**The problem** is that I want to see its **format**, as something like this:

```
{
"tags":{
    "tag":[
               {
               "time":"67",
               "comment":"test 2",
               "id":"18",
               "owner":"xiaoli",
               },
       {
               "time":"30",
               "comment":"",
               "id":"28",
               "owner":"xiaoli",        
       }
        ]
  }
}
```

How can I do this? Or if I can generate a json file?
Thanks.

Comment: `console.dir(jsonResult)` should work in most browsers.

Comment: In fact `console.dir(jsonResult)` returns the object, not the String with " { } " or " [ ] " I want to see, but thanks! @str

Comment: It was not clear to me that you want to get the string representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of your HTTP request is a string.
So you do :

```
jsonResult = JSON.parse(result);
```

to parse this string (result) in an object (jsonResult).

So if you want to see this json as a string, you just have to :

```
console.log(result);
```

Or add it to an element

Comment: thanks that helps, is there any way that I can generate a json file?

Comment: To have the exact same render that you wrote in you're question ? With indents ?

Comment: yes, or not so perfect with indents but a really json file

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/caldwell/renderjson. If this is that you want. Tell me and i'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

are you using a python interpreter to do this?

If so you can use "pretty printing" which should display the son file in a nice way.

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True,
...                  indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
{
    "4": 5,
    "6": 7
}
```

Taken from: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

EDIT:

Sorry just seen that you are using JS. [How can I pretty-print JSON using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript)

perhaps this helps.