# Ionic2 Views , Object is being printed with Double Quotes

Tags: ionic2

When trying to print the custom object by iterating through the for loop via ngFOR
the double quotes are also being printed
Here is my loop
the value is being printed like this
"METRO"
while i want them to appear normal like
METRO

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item-group *ngFor="let g of tp.LegList">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <ion-card>
              <div *ngIf="g" ng-value="some value">
                {{g}} {{g.line}}
                <ion-item>
                  <ion-label (click)="showNextDepartures($event)">{{g.line | json}}</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
              </div>
            </ion-card>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </ion-item-group>
</ion-list>
</ion-item-group>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: `{{g}} {{g.line}}` are you printing entire object? also which line in the code prints METRO?

Comment: <ion-label (click)="showNextDepartures($event)">{{g.line | json}}</ion-label>
g.line > should print 18 while "18" is being printed
i am iterating through the array of custom class object. 
g has all the members .One of them is line and another is type
when i access them via g.line or g.type then double quotes are being printed while i want them to print without double quotes

Comment: why are you sending to json pipe? That is used to pretty print entire object not a property

Comment: hi, i just tried without json and it is now being printed without quotes.Here is the right one
{{g.line}} insted of {{g.line | json}}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308420/angular-2-pipe-that-transforms-json-object-to-pretty-printed-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without [json pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/JsonPipe-pipe.html).
Json pipe is used to pretty print entire object and not a specific property.

```
<ion-label (click)="showNextDepartures($event)">{{g.line}}</ion-label>
```

Comment: pipe would work if you did {{g | json}} . It is generally used to debug json content. Havent seen it used to display anything since it pretty prints