# Displaying JSON in nice format for HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular

I've been looking for a nice way to display JSON and all the answers have a few solutions, but no matter what I try it just makes it one long line with no formatting.  These are all the things I've tried.

`<div>{{ jsonValue | json }}</div>`

`<pre>{{ jsonValue | json}}</pre>`

`<pre [innerHtml]="jsonValue"></pre>`

`import {PrettyJsonModule} from 'angular2-prettyjson';
<pre [innerHtml]="eligibilityView | prettyjson:3"></pre>`

`import {PrettyJsonModule} from 'angular2-prettyjson';
<pre>{{ eligibilityView | prettyjson:3 }}</pre>`

From all the questions I've seen asked, one of these should work, but they all are only a single line with no formatting.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37310013/1009922) should answer your question.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Making the custom pipe did work, so if you want to add it as an answer I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: If you don't mind, I would mark your question as a duplicate of the post that I suggested.

Comment: @ConnorsFan. That's fair.  it wasn't completely that as I actually used innerHtml instead of innerHTML, and I think there was another syntax error that was causing the issue, but in the end going through that other question did result in it working.

Answer (score 0):

I will strongly encourage you to use [Monaco editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) (Open Source by Microsoft that powers VS Code). Rendering complex JSONs (object that contain arrays and arrays of arrays etc,.) gets complicated.

PS: There are call backs to pretty print after load - initially it doesn't pretty print

```js
require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.8.3/min/vs' }});
window.MonacoEnvironment = { getWorkerUrl: () => proxy };

let proxy = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`
 self.MonacoEnvironment = {
  baseUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.8.3/min/'
 };
 importScripts('https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.8.3/min/vs/base/worker/workerMain.js');
`], { type: 'text/javascript' }));

require(["vs/editor/editor.main"], function () {
 let editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
  value: [
   'function x() {',
   '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
   '}'
  ].join('\n'),
  language: 'javascript',
  theme: 'vs-light' 
 });
 
 editor.addListener('didType', () => {
  console.log(editor.getValue());
 });
  
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Some [packages](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1594#issuecomment-534690154) are also offered to help integrate Monaco in Angular applications.