# Angular 2 - Display a formatted JSON string in User Interface

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In my app I have an API call that returns a JSON with the following (simplified) structure:

```
{
   "prop1": "foo",
   "prop2": "bar",
   "details": "{\"title\": \"Sample Konfabulator Widget\", \"name\": \"main_window\", \"width\": 500, \"height\": 500}"
}
```

The `details` prop contains a large stringified JSON that is read from the database.

Now, in the User Interface I want to display a prettified and formatted version of the `details` prop, something like:

[image]

I've tried it with:

```
<pre>{{ apiResponse.details }}</pre>
```

But the entire JSON is displayed in a single line.

The code I've tried is: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkfgvf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37308420/1009922).

Comment: in your demo you need to parse the string into json, you can wrap the string with `JSON.parse`    https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwjaxc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Juan, thanks! a little bit weird, at first thought, that I have to parse the original string into an object, then pass this object to the `json` pipe, that re-converts it to a string, that is well formatted. but now I understood why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `details` it's not a `json` object and that's why it's not being parsed, you will need to wrap it in `JSON.parse()`

```
details: JSON.parse("{\"title\": \"Sample Konfabulator Widget\", \"name\": \"main_window\", \"width\": 500, \"height\": 500}")
```

and you can now display it using the `json` pipe

```
{{ apiResponse.details | json  }}
```

[Updated Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwjaxc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I've put it in a try / catch block, just to make sure that the app doesn't break: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqzkau?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Juan - After parsing the JSON string, the resulting object is displayed with `{{ apiResponse.details | json }}`. I suggest mentioning it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JSON.parse() in you object directly,  so you can create pipe that convert string object in to json.