# angular @Input get object object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have table where when I click the line is displayed in a component different from the table to pass the information I use the @input decorator but when I try to display the result in my other component I have [object Object]

**table.html**

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selected(row)"</tr>
</table>
```

**table.ts**

```
 public selectedArrayParent!: Product;
     selected(row:Product) {
        this.selectedArrayParent = row;
        console.log(this.selectedArrayParent);
      }
```

**info.ts**

```
 @Input() public selectedArrayEnfant!: Product;
```

**info.html**

```
{{selectedArrayEnfant}}
```

Comment: because it is object. You can't show object like that in html. İf you want to see it in html u need to stringy it to see in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant see object in html like that u need to stringfy it. I created one [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hczok7?file=src/app/app.component.html) for you to understand

I created demo pipe for you. This pipe makes objects as string

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'stringfy'
})
export class StringfyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any): any {
    return JSON.stringify(value);
  }

}
```

in html I did put both of them

```
  {{selectedArrayEnfant}}
  {{ selectedArrayEnfant| stringfy}}
```

then result will be

```
[object Object]
{"test":"test"}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, the input param is object type so you have to cast the object to string to display the result.
Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.selectedArrayParent))` to get the JSON in a string format in the selected function.
For html [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308420/angular-2-pipe-that-transforms-json-object-to-pretty-printed-json)