# How do you convert dates in JSON/Bootstrap-Table to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: javascript, json, bootstrap-table

I want to format 2016-09-14T13:46:39+0000 to DD/MM/YYYY. The data is coming from a JSON file/url into a bootstrap-table. Is there a way to format this using bootstrap-table or javascript?

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/9730/)

Thanks,

```
<table data-toggle="table" 
   data-url="https://api.myjson.com/bins/44564"
   data-row-style="rowStyle">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th data-field="createdAt">Created At</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: It might just make sense to search the web for "javascript date format" or something similar, no?

Comment: @DaveNewton I have tried, but it got me confused. :(

Comment: here is the google link https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20change%20date%20format&rct=j

Comment: But there are running examples on the web *and* on Stack Overflow. I'd recommend at least *trying* something before asking someone to do it for you, but maybe that's just me. In general SO is for specific problems as opposed to asking people to do all the work.

Comment: There is an impressive amout and quality of documentation available for this API. http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/ What have you found so far?

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for the advice. I did my research. Those are just small things that I'm stuck at of a bigger project. Sorry for bothering at all means.

Comment: @Igor I've looked into the API but I couldn't find something useful. Thanks! I will dig deep.

Comment: the same answer is here on stack overflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pretty-print JSON using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this will resolve your issue.. Am using [moment](https://momentjs.com) js to format data.. 
..

```js
function dateFormat(value, row, index) {
   return moment(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table data-toggle="table" 
       data-url="https://api.myjson.com/bins/44564"
       data-row-style="rowStyle">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="createdAt" data-formatter="dateFormat">Created At</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: This was a helpful answer for me, although moment.js is now (2023) considered a legacy project (https://momentjs.com/docs/). Instead, I used Luxon to format dates (https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/)