# JSON.stringify refuses to format object

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

JSON.stringify refuses to format object, it keeps everything on a single line.
Does anyone know why it does not work?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>  
    <script>

var obj = {
 "a" : "1547645674576457645",
 "b" : "2790780987908790879087908790879087098",
 "c" : "38907908709879087",
 "d" : "A very long sentance or text1",
 "e" : "A very long sentance or text2",
 "f" : "A very long sentance or text3"

};

// pretty format trick
var myj=JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4);
//var myj=JSON.stringify(obj);
document.write(myj);

</script>

  </head> 
  <body>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: you need to pretty-print it; per Default it doesn't care about formattings

Comment: That *is* formatted.  JSON is a string.  It sounds like you want it beautified.

Comment: Your Answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript try this answer, it might help you out here

Comment: `document.write('<pre>' + myj + '</' + 'pre>');`

Comment: Look at `myj` in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> var myj=JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4);
> ```

You *are* formatting it. That's what the third argument does.

> ```
> document.write(myj);
> ```

Then you are outputting it as HTML.

Spaces and new lines collapse, by default, in HTML, so the formatting is lost by the way you are presenting the JSON.

Wrap it in a `<pre>` element (and consider using `document.createTextNode` / `appendChild` instead of `document.write` so that any `<` and `&` in the data don't have unfortunate side effects).

Comment: document.write('<pre>' + myj + '</' + 'pre>'); Worked perfectly thanks for the quick response.