# Set indentation level for pretty-printing in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, pretty-print

Is there a way to set the indentation level of MongoDB's `pretty` shell command?

Sometimes, deeply nested objects need to be wrapped when pretty-printing. While modules such as [Python's pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.PrettyPrinter) have a setting for the indentation level, [MongoDB's `pretty` API](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.pretty/) does not seem to provide this.

Is there a workaround (any way to set the indentation of pretty-printing)?

Comment: Would the @downvoter care to explain, or not?

Comment: same issue. need set indentation level for `.pretty()` in mongo shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) is a JavaScript shell, you can [use its pretty-printing functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript). For example

```
JSON.stringify(db.runs.find()[0], null, 2)
```

The third parameter of [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

> indicates the number of space characters to use as white space;