# Display Json in react JS div formatted properly

Tags: html, json, reactjs

I am trying to display a JSON object inside a div tag. I need to format it and indent properly. What is the easiest method to do?

Comment: Have you tried anything and it didn't work? Which part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I tried using JSON.stringify inside <pre>. But I'm getting the output displayed with \n and \t, and not indented.

Comment: Try this code:  `JSON.stringify(jsonObject).replace(/[\\n\\t\\r]/g, '')`

Comment: I used JSONPretty library for reactJS as per Henrique's answer and it worked.

Comment: Is there anyway I can display this json indented in a text area

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/pretty-print-json-using-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably have to create your html based on each property of JSON and create your styles accordingly. However, you can use a third party component to do that for you. Check this one out:

https://github.com/chenckang/react-json-pretty

Comment: Is there anyway I can display this json indented in a text area

Answer (score 2):

Just you can use this code:

**See demo here:** https://jsbin.com/homilox/11/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.10.3/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/babel">
    var data = { "speakers": [
        { "firstname": "Ray",
            "lastname": "Villalobos",
            "category": "Front End",
            "title": "Bootstrap & CSS Preprocessors",
            "image": "http://barcampdeland.org/images/speaker_rayvillalobos.jpg",
            "link": "http://iviewsource.com",
            "bio": "Ray Villalobos is a full-time author and teacher at lynda.com. He is author of the book, Exploring Multimedia for Designers. He has more than 20 years experience in developing and programming multimedia projects. Previously at Entravision Communications, he designed and developed a network of radio station and TV web sites. As a senior producer for Tribune Interactive, he was responsible for designing orlandosentinel.com and for creating immersive multimedia projects and Flash games for the site.",
            "description": "As responsive design continues to take over the web, front-end developers and designers have turned to preprocessors and layout systems that simplify their workflow. Lynda.com staff author Ray Villalobos will talk about using the Bootstrap framework from Twitter to scaffold and fast track your responsive design. He'll talk about how you can use CodeKit and LESS to put together designs in hours instead of days."
        }
    ]};
    var Hello = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return <div><pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) }</pre></div>;
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('container'));
  </script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried this. I'm getting the json as a response from an api. Output is displayed with escape characters like \n and \t in a single line