# Convert imple JSON Object into formatted HTML (javascript or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of objects like this:

```
"value": {
  "something": true,
  "another": false,
  "testing": true,
  "bob": "Hello",
  "restrooms": true,
  "price_rating": 1,
}
```

What I simply want to do is render the items inside `value` as HTML. Sort of like:

```
"something": true
"another": false
"testing": true
"bob": "Hello"
"restrooms": true
"price_rating": 1
```

Is there a simple way to do this without writing some complicated `each` and appending each item one at a time? Of note, these objects will have different attributes and number of attributes.

Comment: `value` is just a nested part of the full JSON in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the object to pretty string using [JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220510/2033671) and output the content to a `<pre>` tag

```js
var a = {
  "value": {
    "something": true,
    "another": false,
    "testing": true,
    "bob": "Hello",
    "restrooms": true,
    "price_rating": 1,
  } 
};
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(a.value, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert any object to json string format

```
JSON.stringify(x.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need it as html without json braces and quotes can do something like:

```js
let data = {
    "value": {
      "something": true,
      "another": false,
      "testing": true,
      "bob": "Hello",
      "restrooms": true,
      "price_rating": 1,
    }
  },
  
  displayObj = data.value,
  
  html = Object.keys(displayObj)
  .map(key => key + ': ' + displayObj[key].toString()).join('<br>')

document.body.innerHTML = html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the object into a string and use `replace` function.

```js
var jsonobj = {"value": {
  "something": true,
  "another": false,
  "testing": true,
  "bob": "Hello",
  "restrooms": true,
  "price_rating": 1,
}};

var str = JSON.stringify(jsonobj.value);

str = str.replace(/,/g, '<br/>').replace('{', '').replace('}', '');

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```