# Append parsed json to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest

Hello I want to append the parsed json(which I get from xmlhttprequest) to a html file.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>alert solr response</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js">
</script>
<script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var data = json.facet_counts.facet_dates["dc.date.accessioned_dt"];
            delete data.gap;
            delete data.end;
            delete data.start;
            console.log(data)
            $("#test").append(data); //here is the problem, I could append xhr.Responsetext but this is not what I want
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/solr/search/select?indent=on&rows=0&facet=true&facet.date=dc.date.accessioned_dt&facet.date.start=2016-01-01T00:00:00Z&facet.date.end=2017-12-01T00:00:00Z&facet.date.gap=%2B1MONTH&q=search.resourcetype:2&wt=json&indent=true', true);
    xhr.send(null);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id = "test">This is the json sample: <br></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I know there are lot of similar questions out there and possible duplicates, I am sorry I couldn't use them for my case(Being a noob and all)
Thank you

Comment: Stringify doesn't look nice and is hard to read, I want every field in different line as in json

Comment: `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);` [Go meet god](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript)

Comment: Just a tip if you are using jQuery, [$.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: $("#test").append(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)); doesn't really change anything it's simlar to stringify(data)

Comment: got it, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this a bit if you are using jQuery, when you get your data you got to [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the content using the third argument to get the indentation you want, since it's just plain text you would also have to append it to a `<pre>` tag or set the css at the p tag to: `white-space: pre`

```js
$.get('https://httpbin.org/get').then(function(data) {
  delete data.gap;
  delete data.end;
  delete data.start;

  $("#test").text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="test"></pre>
```

Comment: OP wanted to parse and then delete some json element, you don't have parsing part in your jquery code.