# Prettify JSON in HTML from iframe?

Tags: html, json, iframe

Maybe my problem is simple because there are many similar requests, but I can't find the solution to my problem.

I build an HTML-website which makes a form request to a server. The server responses with a JSON text to this iframe on the website:

```
<iframe name="json_result" src=""></iframe>
```

The problem is, that this json string is on one line and with that not human-readable. How can I make it pretty? (with breaks and tabs, like firefox is doing it normally by its own in a new tab)

I know there are solutions like JSON.stringify() or google/code-prettify, but I don't know how to get the response json text from the iframe into these functions or maybe build some css classes around the iframe which formats the incoming json automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pretty-print JSON using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript)

Comment: I also found JSON.stringify(), but how do I get the content of my iframe into this function and print it instead of the json one liner on my html website?

Comment: Please add more code showing how you make the request and how the iframe is populated.

Comment: I simply make a request to a server with a form, but the response of the server is shown into an iframe as target: <form action="server" method="get" target="json_result">. Maybe the .onload event from iframe can help here, but I'm not good with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to transform the content of the IFrame from the parent site.   I don't think this is possible without reading it using AJAX instead of via an IFrame.