# pretty print JSON in <td> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

from my backend I receive a prettified JSON response (PHP, `json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)`) which I need to show prettified in my table (on my page, in `<td>` tags, NOT in console). The problem is when I put it into `<td>` I get it unprettified (like on a screenshot):
[image: json image]

I tried to put it into `<pre>` tags, or even used `JSON.Stringify()` but it did not work, the output does not look prettified. Any ideas how to fix this would be welcome. Thank you.

**UPD_1**
Thats what I get when using `JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)`
[image]

If I try to `JSON.parse()` first, and then `JSON.tringify()`, nothing happens with my output, it is not prettified either

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pretty-print JSON using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use both `json.stringify()` and `<pre>` tags. Aslong as you don't put your json in a `<pre>` block, it will be parsed as text by the `HTML` parser. If you put it inside the `<pre>` tags, it will be recognized as code.

```js
var json = {"glossary":{"title":"example glossary","GlossDiv":{"title":"S","GlossList":{"GlossEntry":{"ID":"SGML","SortAs":"SGML","GlossTerm":"Standard Generalized Markup Language","Acronym":"SGML","Abbrev":"ISO 8879:1986","GlossDef":{"para":"A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.","GlossSeeAlso":["GML","XML"]},"GlossSee":"markup"}}}}};

$("table tr td pre").html(JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <pre>

      </pre>
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```