# prettify function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, string, function, object

I'm writing a simple PrettyPrint function that only traverses shallowly through strings and objects.

I think it's pretty close

it's just

```
  {
    "name": "Jon",
    "facts": {
      "car": "Ford",
      "address": {
        "city": "New York"
      },
      "watch": "Casio",
      "other": {}
    },

 }
```

the }, and the space after that before the closing bracket, how do I fix that so it outputs as if JSON.Stringify would?

```
  {
    "name": "Jon",
    "facts": {
      "car": "Ford",
      "address": {
        "city": "New York"
      },
      "watch": "Casio",
      "other": {}
    }
 }
```

```js
const exampleJson = {"name":"Jon","facts":{"car":"Ford","address":{"city":"New York"},"watch":"Casio","other": {}}};

const prettify = obj => {

  tabs = n => Array(n).fill(' ').join('');

  let traverse = (obj, tab = 1) => {
    let markup = '{\n';

    Object.entries(obj).forEach(kv => {
      const [key, val] = kv;
      if (typeof val === 'string') {
        const { length } = Object.keys(val);
        markup += `${tabs(tab)} "${key}": "${val}"`;
      } else if (typeof val === 'object') {
        const { length } = Object.keys(val);
        if (length > 0) {
          markup += `,\n${tabs(tab)} "${key}": ${traverse(val, tab+2)},\n`;
        } else {
          markup += `,\n${tabs(tab)} "${key}": {}`;
        }

      }
    })
    
    markup += `\n${tabs(tab - 1)}}`;
    return markup;
  }

  let results = traverse(obj);

  console.log(results);
}

prettify(exampleJson);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pretty-print JSON using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript)

Comment: @imvain2 I'm trying to do this without JSON.Stringify. it's a general recursion question

Comment: In the line below `if(length > 0)` there is a `,\n` that I do not understand in the template literal

Comment: In general, when you need to make a comma separated list of stuff, rather than starting with an empty string and appending each element plus a comma to it, push each element into an array and then join the array to a string with commas as the delimiter.  That will prevent the "final comma" problem.

Comment: @JonasWilms, without it, the ending for address's } would not have a , and would be on the same line as watch

Comment: @JonasWilms It's adding a comma and newline after the last property (if you look closely, no commas are added after each property)

Comment: @totalnoob yes, but that's another mistake: `{ a: "test", b: "test" }` wouldn't add a comma too as you do not add commas to strings. You always want to prepend a comma instead for the first k-v pair.

Comment: Just wanted to add a link to a great site that does exactly this: https://beautifier.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add a comma in this case but not in the other, in one case you prepend it in another you append it in another you do both. That will never work in the general case.

Instead you should use a comma and a newline regardless of the value. Either prepend it to anything except the first

```
 Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value], i) => {
   if(i) markup += ",\n";
   markup += tabs(tab);
   markup += key + ": ";
   // serialize and add value
 });
```

Or append it to anything except the last:

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value], i, { length }) => {
   markup += tabs(tab);
   markup += key + ": ";
   // serialize and add value
   if(i !== length - 1) markup += ",\n";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve both those problems at once by `replace`ing some characters:

```js
const exampleJson = {"name":"Jon","facts":{"car":"Ford","address":{"city":"New York"},"watch":"Casio","other": {}}};

const prettify = obj => {

  tabs = n => Array(n).fill(' ').join('');

  let traverse = (obj, tab = 1) => {
    let markup = '{\n';

    Object.entries(obj).forEach(kv => {
      const [key, val] = kv;
      if (typeof val === 'string') {
        const { length } = Object.keys(val);
        markup += `${tabs(tab)} "${key}": "${val}"`;
      } else if (typeof val === 'object') {
        const { length } = Object.keys(val);
        if (length > 0) {
          markup += `,\n${tabs(tab)} "${key}": ${traverse(val, tab+2)},\n`;
        } else {
          markup += `,\n${tabs(tab)} "${key}": {}`;
        }

      }
    })
    
    markup += `\n${tabs(tab - 1)}}`;
    return markup;
  }

  let results = traverse(obj);

  console.log(results.replace("\,\n\n", "\n"));
}

prettify(exampleJson);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: `{ a: { b: 1 }, c: { d: 1 }}`