# How to convert JSON string sent from a server into a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to be able to convert the JSON string sent from the server into a JavaScript object on a HMTL page. The raw JSON string data is being displayed, but I would rather display it as a JavaScript object instead.

```
case '/get_list':
  if (req.method == 'POST') {
    console.log("POST");
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function(data) {
      body += data;
      console.log("Partial body: " + body);
    });
    req.on('end', async function() {
      console.log("Body: " + body);
      var json = JSON.parse(body)
      console.log("name is " + json.name) // get name

      const {
        Client
      } = require('pg');
      const connectionString = 'postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/app';

      const client = new Client({
        connectionString: connectionString,
      });
      await client.connect(); // create a database connection

      console.log("user input is " + json.name1);
      //Returns the result from the database in a JSON string onto the HTML page    
      const res3 = await client.query('SELECT name, studentno, proname FROM applications WHERE name =$1 LIMIT 1', [json.name1]);
      await client.end();
      // json = res2.rows;
      json = res3.rows;
      var obj = JSON.parse(res3.rows);
      var json_str_new = JSON.stringify(json); //working
      console.log(obj);
      console.log(json_str_new);
      res.end(json_str_new);
    });

  }
  break;
```

```
Actual results
{"name":"jake","studentno":10001212,"proname":"asdasdas"}

Expected/required results 
{
  name: 'jake',
  studentno: 10001212,
  proname: 'asdasdas'
}
```

Comment: Parse it on the client? If you're using the Fetch API, call the `json` method of the response?

Comment: [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or [`response.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) if you're using fetch

Comment: `JSON.parse` converts json into an object, but I don't know what you mean by "I would rather display it as a JavaScript object".  Are you just looking for the pretty-print indentation?

Comment: (If so, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript )

Comment: From the OP's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55676856/how-to-convert-json-string-sent-from-a-server-into-a-javascript-object#comment98038990_55676953), this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on using the JSON for anything, as in traversing and reading the data from that, then `JSON.parse()` is exactly what you need. Pretty-printing is something only useful for humans, so unless you're exclusively using the output for human consumption, the result you have should be fine.

However, if you *are* going to just show the data, then I would recommend just formatting the output into some `HTML`/`CSS` display.

But assuming you are planning on using the data for something, as mentioned before and by others, `JSON.parse()` is all you need to generate a JS object.

Comment: @STEVE.R - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript