# How to view file directory from HTML page of Node server

Tags: node.js

I currently have a Node server set up with allows the user to upload files in Node using file upload. I would also like the user to be able to view the file directory which contains all the uploaded files, but am unsure of how to go about it.

I would like to be able to see all the uploaded files within a HTML page that can be served to the user, which shows all the files uploaded, and will be able to access and open the files that have been uploaded.

Comment: @Jean thanks for handling this. Not sure if the username was reverted due to the temporary suspension or due to your actions specifically, but their original username was [STEVE.R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55676856#comment98039060_55676953).

Comment: yeah, I know. But I'm not sure user wants to "dissociate" posts/name from SO Account. Changing name is all right. Defacing posts isn't.