# How do I console log props to a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a multi-step form in React and I would like to console.log the JSON of the props at the end with all the inputted information. How would I do this?

Here is my code:

I tried the deconstructed props in the arrow function component but it didn't work.

```
const Final = ({
  values: { one, two... }
}) => {

 console.log(JSON.stringify(Final);
```

I managed to log the info this way, but it's not exactly what I would like:

```
  console.log(
    "Value One: " + one,
    "Value Two: " + two,
    ....);
```

*I deleted my previous question by accident*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pretty-print JSON using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would probably just take `props` as an argument rather than destructuring:

```
const Final = (props) => {

 console.log(JSON.stringify(props));
```