# Print array to console elegantly

Tags: node.js

How would I get the following object:

```
[ 'hello everyone!', { testing: 1 }, 'another:', { state: 1 } ]
```

To print as the following:

```
hello everyone! { 
    testing: 1 
} another: { 
    state: 1 
}
```

The objects in the array can be heavily nested.

I use this right now, but feels like it's heavy:

```
const messages = [ 'hello everyone!', { testing: 1 }, 'another:', { state: 1 } ];
let string = '';
messages.forEach(element => {
    string += ' ';
    if (typeof element === 'string') {
        string += element;
    } else {
        string += util.inspect(element, { showHidden: false, depth: null, compact: false });
    }
});
console.log(string);
```

Bonus for elegant code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pretty-print JSON using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript)

Comment: ^ The author doesn't want array brackets to be visible, so it is different.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(yourData));
```

This should help see the data better in the terminal. Not elegant or anything but simple at least. Admittedly doesn't give the nesting but shows the full object and should maintain to do so with deeper nesting.

[image]

As mentioned in the comments by [Gavin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2244284/gavin) this also has a pretty-printing argument to help achieve the nesting.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(yourData, null, 2));
```

Which would give you

[image]

Comment: +1 to this. Also note stringify's third parameter allows to specify whitespace for pretty-printing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: ^ The author doesn't want array brackets to be visible, so it is different.

Comment: are you sure? because I see brackets, just not on the same line

Comment: In author's example there are no commas, no double quotes and no external array `[]` brackets in the output.

Comment: ahh okay i see mb

Comment: Unfortunetly this adds `"` around the JSON object and includes the array brackets and inclues commas which I'm trying to avoid!

Comment: Updated with my example, but it feels heavy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. [SO Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript)

```
console.log(JSON.stringify([ 'hello everyone!', { testing: 1 }, 'another:', { state: 1 } ], null, 2))
```