# Javascript- convert content in textbox to key value pair

Tags: javascript, key-value

I have a textbox which accepts user defined key value pairs like:
{'Apple':'Red', 'Lemon':'Green'} and i want it to be converted to an array of key value pair.
I have code:

```
var color= document.getElementById('txtColor').value;
```

The problem is i get it just as a string if i try: `color['Apple']` it shows undefined; whereas i expect 'Red'. How can i do the conversion so that i get something like:

```
var color={'Apple':'Red', 'Lemon':'Green'}
```

and get value 'Red' on `color['Apple']`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could enforce JSON syntax in the textbox (in your case: replace the single quotes with double quotes), then you can simply parse the content into a native object using ```JSON.parse(color)```

Comment: Replacing single quotes with double quotes in the textbox and then JSON.parse for the value did the trick. Thanks! Just a clarification or doubt more on that. How can i make it ignore case sensitive. Like if user gives apple in the string and in my code i need to check for the value. i dont get 'Red' in that case if i have in my code 'Apple'. I saw some codes to convert to lowercase or uppercase etc; but is there another way to handle the situatiion. Thanks.

Comment: No, there isn’t, not if you want to be able to access the value via `color['Foo']` afterwards, then you need to convert a possible key `foo` inside of your data array directly. (But if such simple case discrepancies are a case for concern here already, then the possibility of the user messing up the pseudo-JSON syntax here is probably even higher …)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar usecase. You have to `JSON.parse()` the value.

```js
var obj = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('txtColor').value.replace(/'/g, '"'));

console.log(obj['Apple']);
```

```html
<textarea id="txtColor">{'Apple':'Red', 'Lemon':'Green'}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume following

```
let color = document.getElementById('txtColor').value; // This line returns {'Apple':'Red', 'Lemon':'Green'}
```

If I'm correct you can do following

```
try {
  // Here you can write logic for format json ex. Convert single quotes to double quotes 
  // This may help to convert well formatted json string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript
  let colorJson = JSON.parse(color);
  console.log(colorJson["Apple"]) // This will return your expected value.
} catch(e) {
  console.log('Invalid json format')
}
```

Comment: A `try/catch` may be needed to prevent error if the user entered an invalid JSON.

Comment: His example is not valid JSON, since it uses single quotes.

Comment: I get an error: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2 in the line JSON.parse(color);

Answer (score 1):

```js
var color = document.getElementById('txtColor').value;

//JSON.stringify will validate the JSON string
var jsonValidString = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + color + ")"));

//If JSON string is valid then we can conver string to JSON object
var JSONObj = JSON.parse(jsonValidString);

//We can use JSON.KeyName or JSON["KeyName"] both way you can get value
console.log(JSONObj.Apple, " --- ", JSONObj["Apple"]);
console.log(JSONObj.Lemon, " --- ", JSONObj["Lemon"]);
```

```html
<input id="txtColor" value="{'Apple':'Red', 'Lemon':'Green'}" type="text" />
```

Comment: *NOTE* : Always try to validate string when you convert string to JSON object.