# How to I can Array of strings into object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can anyone help me in this.

```
[
 "{proId: 845,particularProduct: 1153,parQuantity: 2,rPrice: 899,numItems: 100}",
 "{proId: 848,particularProduct: 1157,parQuantity: 2,rPrice: 1009,numItems: 3}"
]
```

How Can I get the value of proId, particularProduct, etc

Comment: Fix whatever's serving you that essentially broken input so that it gives you proper JSON instead, and then you can JSON.parse it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pretty-print JSON using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the array and use **eval()** method to make elements as object:

```
var data = [
 "{proId: 845,particularProduct: 1153,parQuantity: 2,rPrice: 899,numItems: 100}",
 "{proId: 848,particularProduct: 1157,parQuantity: 2,rPrice: 1009,numItems: 3}"
]

data.forEach(function (item) {
   var parsedData = eval('(' + item + ')');
   console.log(parsedData.proId)
})
```

**Output:**

```
845
848
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is correct, in a way: it is an array with two strings in it. These two strings have a certain resemblance with JSON again, but are *not* valid JSON. However, the whole thing can be parsed with

```
arr.forEach((el,i)=>arr[i]=eval('('+el+')'))
console.log(arr[0].proId,arr[0].particularProduct);
```