# To customize Angular material mattooltip and format data to show in tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to show the data in tooltip in json format as attached in the pic.

I am able to load the data in tooltip(but not the way it is formatted in the picture attached).

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Alert">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Alert </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                        <span matTooltip="{{(row?.conditionals)?(row.conditionals | json):''}}">{{row.Alert}}</span> 
                </td>
 </ng-container>
```

Stackblitz link. The html and ts code is present in stackblitz link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-xngsaq?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.ts

In the tooltip Conditionals, Offset, Alert needs to be shown as in the attached pic, when we hover on first column.

**#EDIT1**
*I also have tried basic html tooltip if anyone can suggest formatting data on this that would also work for me*

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-ik3f8e?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.css

For reference one of the so links
[pretty-print JSON using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/pretty-print-json-using-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: You mean like this?? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-ytcdaj

Comment: @ManirajMurugan I am able to show the data in the format you have done in your stackblitz link but want to match with the attached picture

Comment: Do you want to show under alert mMessage fiead right ?

Comment: @errorau I have updated the stackblitz , yes when we hover on first column the data is coming up in tooltip but not formatted as in the attcahed pic , thanks

Comment: Showing such huge text in tooltip is not a good idea. instead show it in dialog where you can customize the way you want.

Comment: @Allabakash ,Sorry but that is what the requirement is :) , it would be great if you could help in the formatting , it might be looking more tight in stackblitz link :)

Comment: I updated my aswer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think, i fixed it

```
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
 font-size: 15px;
 white-space: pre-wrap;
 color: gray !important;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
 border:1px solid gray;
 max-width: unset !important;
}
```

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-g28f5w?embed=1&file=app/tooltip-overview-example.css
--Update--

Add `matTooltipClass`

```
<span [matTooltipClass]="{ 'tool-tip': true }" matTooltip="{{(row?.conditionals)?(row.conditionals | json):''}}">{{row.Alert}}</span> 

then change css file like 


.tool-tip {
     font-size: 15px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    color: gray !important;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) !important;
    border:1px solid gray;
    max-width: unset !important;

    }
```

For a button

```
 <button mat-raised-button
    [matTooltipClass]="{ 'tool-tip': true }" matTooltip="{{(row?.conditionals)?(row.conditionals | json):''}}"
    aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over">
```

Action

Comment: thanks , I have updated the following link using normal html tooltip , https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-deyuyp?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html , can you suggest on modifying this if possible

Comment: @Enthu I update answer if you open encapsulation line it will work

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have accepted I clicked on bounty but it will allow only after 6hrs , anyways I'll do that, one more part if you can help how can place a button inisde the tooltip and which upon being clicked opnes a material dialog

Comment: Nice :) https://ybin.me/p/835393b933c929fd#KIwXUyx/1Xkvge8GcP7rQ8OP2BQuZHC+VyuXVm+tEeU= here for a button use this tooltip

Answer (score 0):

try with `white-space: pre-wrap;`

```
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
   font-size: 15px;
  background: green;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: thanks , but I need to format the data as well(same as in the attached picture) :) , now I have started using normal html tooltip , https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-vsern6?file=app/tooltip-overview-example.html , if you can suggest to format data

Comment: you can try with this `white-space: pre;`

Comment: thanks, white-space : pre works but not in the way I have attached in the picture , :) , can we format exactly like we have in the picture